# How do I write non-ASCII characters using echo?

Tags: linux, bash, ascii, echo, non-ascii-characters

How do I write non-[ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters using echo? Is there an escape sequence, such as `\012` or something like that?

I want to append ASCII characters to a file using:

```
echo ?? >> file
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use

```
echo -e "\012"
```

Comment: This requires functionality that's entirely noncompliant with POSIX (not just an extension, but *actively disallowed* by the specification, which allows no flags other than `-n` to be honored), and won't be honored by even bash in POSIX mode if the `xpg_echo` flag is set.

Comment: Note, the format is `\0...`. So if you want octal 101, you use `"\0101"`. You must have a leading zero with `echo -e`.

Answer (score 40):

If you care about portability, you'll drop *echo* and use *printf(1)*:

```
printf '\012'
```

Comment: ...or, if taking the escape sequence from an untrusted source, `printf '%b' '\012'`, to honor such sequences but not other format string contents.

Comment: note that the format is `\NNN`, not `\0...`. So if you want Octal 101, use `printf '\101'`, not `printf '\0101'`

Answer (score 14):

On my terminal,

```
printf '\012' >>output.txt
```

works for both the octal representation of the ascii character, and the corresponding hexadecimal:

```
printf '\xA' >>output.txt
```

The command

```
echo -en '\012' >>output.txt
```

however, does not function properly.  Only hexadecimals seem to work with echo -e.  The -n removes the default extra newline from echo.

Comment: _My_ question was actually on how to print hexadecimal to a terminal - found this through google, and this answered my question very well. It also answers the asker's question. It deserves more points.

Comment: `echo -en '\012' >>output.txt` worked perfectly for me on both Ubuntu 18.04 GNU bash v4.4.19 and macOS mojave GNU bash, version 3.2.57. It's a little easier to visualize if you use a visible character like `'\0101'` (`A`).

Comment: `Only hexadecimals seem to work with echo -e`. This isn't true, in my experience. See a bunch of my examples using hex, octal, or mixed escape codes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65878758/4561887) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings/65878993#65878993). Granted, my examples are primarily for single (`'`) and double (`"`) quotes, which are ASCII chars.

Answer (score 9):

You can use ANSI-C Quoting with `echo`:

```
echo $'\012' # octal

echo $'\x0a' # hex
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, as this works not just in echo, but in mv as well. This in combination with xxd to get the hex values, then I can rename my incorrectly encoded filenames to exactly what they have to be.

Answer (score 2):

I took non-ASCII to mean Unicode, at least in my case, but `printf "\x##"` wasn't enough for my 2-byte solution, so I used this slightly different syntax instead:

```
> printf "\u25ba"
►
```

Answer (score 2):

### Brief

```sh
echo -e 'toto\010\010ti'   # OUTPUTS: toti
echo -e '\x41'             # OUTPUTS: A
echo -e '\u03B1'           # OUTPUTS: α
echo -e '\U1F413 <= \U1F1EB\U1F1F7' # OUTPUTS  <=
```

### Doc

From `man bash` > /BUILTIN/ > /^ *echo/

```
              \0nnn  the eight-bit character whose value is the octal value nnn (zero  to
                     three octal digits)
              \xHH   the eight-bit character whose value is the hexadecimal value HH (one
                     or two hex digits)
              \uHHHH the Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is the hexadecimal
                     value HHHH (one to four hex digits)
              \UHHHHHHHH
                     the Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is the hexadecimal
                     value HHHHHHHH (one to eight hex digits)
```

### Link

- Ascii list: `man ascii`
- [Unicode list](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/337989/257838): script on StackOverflow