# How can I keep quotes in Bash arguments?

Tags: bash, quotes

I have a Bash script where I want to keep quotes in the arguments passed.

Example:

```
./test.sh this is "some test"
```

Then I want to use those arguments, and reuse them, including quotes and quotes around the whole argument list.

I tried using `\"$@\"`, but that removes the quotes inside the list.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: `\"$@\"` is wrong -- it adds **literal** quotes to the first and last arguments. `"$@"`, without the backslashes, is correct: in it, the quotes are purely syntactic. See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for an explanation of why passing argument lists around as strings is innately incorrect in shell.

Comment: Charles is right. When you want to pass all the arguments to another script, or function, use "$@" (without escaping your quotes).

Comment: See this answer: [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42082956/6862601).

Comment: Related: [How do I use a Bash variable (string) containing quotes in a command?](https://superuser.com/q/360966/11574)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/445477/162125

Comment: Related: *[How to escape single quotes within single quoted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/)*

Answer (score -18, accepted):

Just use single quotes around the string with the double quotes:

```
./test.sh this is '"some test"'
```

So the double quotes of inside the single quotes were also interpreted as string.

But I would recommend to put the whole string between single quotes:

```
 ./test.sh 'this is "some test" '
```

In order to understand what the shell is doing or rather interpreting arguments in scripts, you can write a little script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $@
echo "$@"
```

Then you'll see and test, what's going on when calling a script with different strings

Comment: How can this be the accepted answer? This requires the caller of the script to know that he meeds double quotation although this can be handled in the script without altering the way the caller builds the parameter list

Comment: If you have no control over `./test.sh` then this is the correct answer, but if you are authoring `./test.sh`, then [the answer from Chris Dodd](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1669548/185101) is the better solution.

Comment: Not just if you have no control over `test.sh`, but only in the scenario where `test.sh` is **written to use `eval` unsafely** is this appropriate. And frankly, if something is using `eval` unsafely, that's probably a pretty good reason to stop using that thing.

Comment: Wtf is wrong with people here. How is this an accepted answer. It passes the responsibility to the caller.

Comment: Although this is correct, it is basically "you don't"-type answer. It doesn't really answer the question. Nor does it adhere to the SO rules for answers. If anything, a more informative explanation of why you don't can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10836225/4687565

Comment: I've extended the answer because it wasn't visible on first sight where the differences of the both calls were. It took a while until I've seen the single quotes at @yuku answer

Comment: I take that back, for an instant i read it as `$*` instead of `$@`, indeed this is the right answer. The link here clarifies it [Bash $* and $@](https://eklitzke.org/bash-%24*-and-%24%40).

Answer (score 147):

Using `"$@"` will substitute the arguments as a list, without resplitting them on whitespace (they were split once when the shell script was invoked), which is generally exactly what you want if you just want to repass the arguments to another program.

Note that this is a special form and is only recognized as such if it appears exactly this way.  If you add anything else in the quotes the result will get combined into a single argument.

Comment: I think he means the quotes are part of the argument string, not part of the bash syntax.

Comment: To clarify, this answer is perfect: it is just like the other answers that tries to re-add quote around each argument. This DOES NOT just add two quotes around the whole argument list, but around each individual argument.

Comment: @qwertzguy is incorrect.  The double quotes will be stripped before the variable enters the arguments list.

Comment: This is the top-rated answer.  While it is correct per se, it doesn't address the question really.

Comment: @TorstenBronger: Since the question is completely unclear, this is answering my best guess for what the OP actually wants.

Comment: Yes, I agree that it is unclear.  And that your answer has its value in its own right.  And I really do not grudge you any upvote.  But still ... this is the answer to another question.  :)

Comment: @TorstenBronger: the upvotes indicate that this is the asnwer to the question that most people have when they search for their question and hit this page, even if its not the answer to what the OP was trying to ask.

Comment: how would you use the "$@" format for passing the params to `xargs` ? would it work without the re-quoting trick? i do not think so

Comment: @Hofi: `xargs` doesn't reinterpret or reparse its arguments in any way, so there should be no need for additional quoting (unless you're doing something like `xargs sh `...)

Comment: @ChrisDodd i'm confused now, will you plz clarify, how would xargs do that in the following case `echo "$@" | xargs -t defaults write "${BUNDLEID}" "${KEY}" -dict`  in this case if one of the input parameters is like "pararm with spaces" than it would not work without the extra quoting trick

Comment: @Hofi:  You can do something like `find <some find args> | xargs program "$@"` and it will pass the arguments of the original script or function on to `program` with no reinterpretation.  If you want to xargs to not split its INPUT on spaces, you need something like `{ for a in "$@"; do echo -en "$a\\x0"; done; } | xargs -0 program`

Comment: @ChrisDodd sorry, but neither above will work if you have to just pass strings with spaces inside, try these  `echo  "nospace" "yes space"  | xargs ls  "$@"` `echo  "nospace" "yes space"  | xargs -0 ls ` `echo  '"nospace"' '"yes space"'   | xargs ls `    In the first case 3 separate name passed to `ls` by `xargs` and in the 2nd case only one (as expected) only the 3rd case working correctly (not surprisingly)

Comment: @Hofi: Those are all because you need the correct quoting for `echo` -- `xargs` and `"$@"` are irrelevant.  Try `echo -ne "nospace\x0yes space\x0"` as I suggested.

Comment: @TorstenBronger, it absolutely does address the question, if what you're doing is passing through arguments you received -- which is the only context where "keeping" quotes makes sense. If your script was run with `./yourscript this is "some test"`, then running `./anotherscript "$@"` will pass `this`, `is`, and `some test` as three distinct arguments through to `anotherscript`, just as if a user had run `./anotherscript this is "some test"`.

Comment: @Hofi, `xargs` is a special case, and it's generally accepted that it's broken-by-design (inasmuch as it tries to perform shell-like string-splitting on its literal input). Indeed, if you look at reputable references such as [the Wooledge wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Actions_in_bulk:_xargs.2C_-print0_and_-exec_.2B-), you find warnings akin to: "*xargs by default is **extremely** dangerous, and should never be used without the nonstandard `-0` extension.*". That said, xargs only dequotes its stdin, **not** its argument vector.

Comment: @Hofi, ...thus, it's completely valid to run `xargs something "$@"` -- it's when you're feeding content to **stdin** of `xargs` that precautions such as `printf '%s\0' "$@" | xargs -0 something` are needed.

Comment: This is definitely not the answer we are looking for even with top vote. A example why we need this is, for example, I need to use ssh host -t "remoteCmd $@", The remote command expect some argument with a string with spaces in between which we do need to keep quote.

Comment: @JianwuChen: you want the quotes just around the `$@` -- `ssh host -t remoteCmd "$@"`.  The special expansion doesn't apply if you include anything else in the quotes.

Answer (score 78):

There are two safe ways to do this:

#### 1. [Shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html): `${variable@Q}:`

When expanding a variable via `${variable@Q}`:

> The expansion is a string that is the value of parameter quoted in a format that can be reused as input.

Example:

```
$ expand-q() { for i; do echo ${i@Q}; done; }  # Same as for `i in "$@"`...
$ expand-q word "two words" 'new
> line' "single'quote" 'double"quote'
word
'two words'
$'new\nline'
'single'\''quote'
'double"quote'
```

#### 2. `printf %q "$quote-me"`

`printf` supports quoting internally. The [manual's entry for `printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands) says:

> `%q`  Causes printf to output the corresponding argument in a format that can be reused as shell input.

Example:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
printf "%q\n" "$@"
$
$ ./test.sh this is "some test" 'new
>line' "single'quote" 'double"quote'
this
is
some\ test
$'new\nline'
single\'quote
double\"quote
$
```

---

Note the second way is a bit cleaner if displaying the quoted text to a human.

Related: For Bash, [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) sh and [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) (executable `zsh`): [Quote string with single quotes rather than backslashes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/445469/143394)

Comment: This worked for me. In a function I used:
local _quoted=$( printf ' "%q"' "$@" )
This answer looks like the most robust.

Comment: Interesting, but it does add backslashes to spaces and characters like bang.  In some cases this doesn't matter, but it converts a single unquoted ! to /! which doesn't work for me.

Comment: `!` needs to be quoted:

Unquoted: `$ echo !foo` `-bash: !foo: event not found`  Quoted: `$ echo \!foo` `!foo`

Comment: The 1st method `expand-q` has an error: `${i@Q}` should be `${i:Q}`  otherwise it fails with `bash: ${i@Q}: bad substitution`

Comment: @arielf What version of `bash`? It works as shown on `$BASH_VERSION 
4.4.19(1)-release`.

What you're doing is probably a side effect of `${parameter:offset}` where `offset` is `0`, (possibly because `atoi()` of `Q` gives `0`).

Comment: That may be the reason. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.4 (LTS). Latest bash on this system is  `4.3.48(1)-release`

Comment: I found `${*@Q}` to be very useful for passing all command line arguments to a subsequent shell invocation, in my case one due to a `sg` call to change group. Thanks for this answer!

Comment: @MvG I wish I'd run into a comment like yours sooner; I'm doing the *exact* same thing! I can confirm that `${*@Q}` is the perfect solution at the end of my long search

Comment: In example one, my bash (version 5.1.8) also puts the first line `word` in quotes, as `'word'`, which is different from yours. It look bad in my case because I see a lot of unnecessary quotes. How do you achieve your result? (no quote for `word`)

Comment: ${i@Q) does not work for me as it adds (single) quotes to everything, needed or not, which breaks the parameter passing.  printf escaping worked best.  Thanks!

Answer (score 49):

[Yuku's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668649/how-can-i-keep-quotes-in-bash-arguments/1668686#1668686) only works if you're the only user of your script, while [Dennis Williamson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668649/how-can-i-keep-quotes-in-bash-arguments/1669493#1669493) is great if you're mainly interested in printing the strings, and expect them to have no quotes-in-quotes.

Here's a version that can be used if you want to pass all arguments as one big quoted-string argument to the `-c` parameter of `bash` or `su`:

```
#!/bin/bash
C=''
for i in "$@"; do
    i="${i//\\/\\\\}"
    C="$C \"${i//\"/\\\"}\""
done
bash -c "$C"
```

So, *all* the arguments get a quote around them (harmless if it wasn't there before, for this purpose), but we also escape any escapes and then escape any quotes that were already in an argument (the syntax `${var//from/to}` does global substring substitution).

You could of course only quote stuff which already had whitespace in it, but it won't matter here. One utility of a script like this is to be able to have a certain predefined set of environment variables (or, with su, to run stuff as a certain user, without that mess of double-quoting everything).

---

I had reason to do this in a POSIX way with minimal forking, which lead to this script (the last *printf* there outputs the command line used to invoke the script, which you should be able to copy-paste in order to invoke it with equivalent arguments):

```
#!/bin/sh
C=''
for i in "$@"; do
    case "$i" in
        *\'*)
            i=`printf "%s" "$i" | sed "s/'/'\"'\"'/g"`
            ;;
        *) : ;;
    esac
    C="$C '$i'"
done
printf "$0%s\n" "$C"
```

I switched to `''` since shells also interpret things like `$` and `!!` in `""`-quotes.

Comment: Use array instead? I'll post an example below.

Comment: This is almost perfect, but I would suggest one minor modification - escaping all `\` before appending to `$C` - i.e. adding `i="${i//\\/\\\\}"` otherwise arguments like `"\\\"asdf"` will fail.

Comment: Good catch! Thanks, edited and added. I can now do `$ ./escape-args-to-bash echo "\\\"asdf"` to get `\"asdf` just like `$ echo "\\\"asdf"` gives `\"asdf`. (In case the above comment isn't editable, the single ` was probably meant to be a backslash in backticks that ended up escaping the backtick instead – is there a corollary to Muphry's Law here? :))

Comment: @unhammer Thank you so much, this works awesome!

Comment: ℹ️ Same as just: `"${@@Q}"`

Comment: Oh that's interesting, what do you call that? It doesn't seem to do the same thing though, since it splits it up into several params (much like `"$@"`), so you can't use it as the single argument of `-c` – also bash-only.

Comment: `man bash` says it's a **Parameter transformation**. Could use that in the bash-version instead of the regex replace, giving `C=''; for i in "$@"; do C="$C ${i@Q}"; done; bash -c "$C"`

Answer (score 37):

If it's safe to make the assumption that an argument that contains white space must have been (and should be) quoted, then you can add them like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
whitespace="[[:space:]]"
for i in "$@"
do
    if [[ $i =~ $whitespace ]]
    then
        i=\"$i\"
    fi
    echo "$i"
done
```

Here is a sample run:

```
$ ./argtest abc def "ghi jkl" $'mno\tpqr' $'stu\nvwx'
abc
def
"ghi jkl"
"mno    pqr"
"stu
vwx"
```

You can also *insert* literal tabs and newlines using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd> within double or single quotes instead of using escapes within `$'...'`.

A note on *inserting* characters in Bash: If you're using Vi key bindings (`set -o vi`) in Bash (Emacs is the default - `set -o emacs`), you'll need to be in *insert* mode *in order to insert characters*. In Emacs mode, you're always in insert mode.

Comment: But how to check if the user has quoted say, the 1st argument?

Comment: @TonyBarganski: The shell strips quotes when arguments are processed before they're passed to the program receiving them. It's not possible to tell whether there were _outer_ quotes on an argument.

Answer (score 25):

I needed this for forwarding all arguments to another interpreter.
What ended up right for me is:

```
bash -c "$(printf ' %q' "$@")"
```

Example (when named as forward.sh):

```
$ ./forward.sh echo "3 4"
3 4
$ ./forward.sh bash -c "bash -c 'echo 3'"
3
```

(Of course the actual script I use is more complex, involving in my case nohup and redirections etc., but this is the key part.)

Answer (score 14):

Like [Tom Hale said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668649/how-can-i-keep-quotes-in-bash-arguments/39463371#39463371), one way to do this is with `printf` using `%q` to quote-escape.

For example:

**send_all_args.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$#" -lt 1 ]; then
 quoted_args=""
else
 quoted_args="$(printf " %q" "${@}")"
fi

bash -c "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )/receiver.sh${quoted_args}"
```

**send_fewer_args.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$#" -lt 2 ]; then
 quoted_last_args=""
else
 quoted_last_args="$(printf " %q" "${@:2}")"
fi

bash -c "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )/receiver.sh${quoted_last_args}"
```

**receiver.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
for arg in "$@"; do
  echo "$arg"
done
```

Example usage:

```
$ ./send_all_args.sh
$ ./send_all_args.sh a b
a
b
$ ./send_all_args.sh "a' b" 'c "e '
a' b
c "e
$ ./send_fewer_args.sh
$ ./send_fewer_args.sh a
$ ./send_fewer_args.sh a b
b
$ ./send_fewer_args.sh "a' b" 'c "e '
c "e
$ ./send_fewer_args.sh "a' b" 'c "e ' 'f " g'
c "e
f " g
```

Comment: This is a great example because it contains a reproducible test for forwarding the arguments through something like `sh -c`.  Plus, it works ;-).  Not all of the others do.

Answer (score 10):

Just use:

```
"${@}"
```

For example:

```
# cat t2.sh
for I in "${@}"
do
   echo "Param: $I"
done
# cat t1.sh
./t2.sh "${@}"

# ./t1.sh "This is a test" "This is another line" a b "and also c"
Param: This is a test
Param: This is another line
Param: a
Param: b
Param: and also c
```

Comment: This doesn't allow the arguments to be forwarded to a bash -c invocation.  For that you need something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/42588600/125349

Comment: This worked for me, able to forward one to other to another.

Answer (score 6):

I changed [unhammer's example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668649/how-can-i-keep-quotes-in-bash-arguments/8723305#8723305) to use array.

```
printargs() { printf "'%s' " "$@"; echo; };  # http://superuser.com/a/361133/126847

C=()
for i in "$@"; do
    C+=("$i")  # Need quotes here to append as a single array element.
done

printargs "${C[@]}"  # Pass array to a program as a list of arguments.
```

Comment: Is it possible to use `"${C[@]}"` as an argument to `bash -c` there? E.g. if your script was called with the arguments `echo foo\"bar"'"fie`

Comment: e.g. `foo=( echo bar\"fie"'"fum ); C='';for i in "${foo[@]}"; do C="$C \"${i//\"/\\\"}\""; done; bash -c "$C" ` gives `bar"fie'fum`

Comment: Though the code looks cleaner, you still loose the quotes

Answer (score 6):

My problem was similar and I used mixed ideas posted here.

We have a server with a PHP script that sends e-mails. And then we have a second server that connects to the 1st server via SSH and executes it.

The script name is the same on both servers and both are actually executed via a bash script.

On server 1 (local) bash script we have just:

```
/usr/bin/php /usr/local/myscript/myscript.php "$@"
```

This resides on `/usr/local/bin/myscript` and is called by the remote server. It works fine even for arguments with spaces.

But then at the remote server we can't use the same logic because the 1st server will not receive the quotes from `"$@"`. I used the ideas from JohnMudd and Dennis Williamson to recreate the options and parameters array with the quotations. I like the idea of adding escaped quotations only when the item has spaces in it.

So the remote script runs with:

```
CSMOPTS=()
whitespace="[[:space:]]"
for i in "$@"
do
    if [[ $i =~ $whitespace ]]
    then
        CSMOPTS+=(\"$i\")
    else
        CSMOPTS+=($i)
    fi
done

/usr/bin/ssh "$USER@$SERVER" "/usr/local/bin/myscript ${CSMOPTS[@]}"
```

Note that I use `"${CSMOPTS[@]}"` to pass the options array to the remote server.

Comment: the above slightly fails: -opt="value" becomes "-opt=value"

Comment: I am not using `=` in my scripts, but since the `\"` are only added when spaces are detected, `-opt="value"` will actually become `-opt=value`. something like `-opt="another value"` would be sent as `"-opt=another value"` but since my setup sends it to another script on another machine it is still interpreted as a single token as intended. The remote script receives `-opt=another value` as a single token without the quotations. Things are very different if running locally though. You wouldn't even need to escape the `\"` for example.

Answer (score 3):

Quotes are interpreted by Bash and are not stored in command line arguments or variable values.

If you want to use quoted arguments, you have to quote them each time you use them:

```
val="$3"
echo "Hello, World!" > "$val"
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Gary S. Weaver has shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668649/how-can-i-keep-quotes-in-bash-arguments/42588600#42588600) in his source code tips, the trick is to call Bash with parameter '-c' and then quote the next.

E.g.

```
bash -c "<your program> <parameters>"
```

or

```
docker exec -it <my docker> bash -c "$SCRIPT $quoted_args"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pass all arguments to Bash **from another programming language** (for example, if you'd want to execute `bash -c` or `emit_bash_code | bash`), use this:

- escape all single quote characters you have with `'\''`.
- then, surround the result with singular quotes

The argument of `abc'def` will thus be converted to `'abc'\''def'`. The characters `'\''` are interpreted as following: the already existing quoting is terminated with the first first quote, then the escaped singular single quote `\'` comes, then the new quoting starts.

Comment: No. Don't escape arguments as text embedded in the code; instead, use an interface from your other programming language that lets you pass an *array* of arguments, and pass each item in its own array element. This means folks shouldn't ever use `system()`; fortunately, its deficiencies have been recognized for decades, so it's rarely the only choice.

Comment: In Python, for example, one can pass an array rather than a string to a `subprocess`-family call. In C, one can use `execv` or `posix_spawn`. In Java, one can use one of the array-based interfaces in `Runtime.exec()`; etc, etc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sorry, but my answer starts from the word "if". See "for example" if it's not clear enough... If you can just call a CLI by using an array of arguments, of course that's better. In the situation I describe, however, it's just not possible (`bash -c` or `another_program | bash`).

Comment: It's *absolutely* possible. `subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', 'code that uses "$1" and "$2"', "_", "value for $1", "value for $2"])`, f/e, starts bash from Python while passing two values in a way that keeps them out-of-band from code. The pipe-to-bash pattern simply shouldn't be followed at all, but one can get code that way while similarly passing data out-of-band with any of the available equivalents to `another_program | bash -s 'value for $1' 'value for $2'`

Comment: Even if you're using a language that provides nothing but `system()`, you can use `setenv()` to store your literal values as environment variables and then pass the code as a constant, which refers to those variables from the body.

Comment: `The pipe-to-bash pattern simply shouldn't be followed at all` -- you could be right. That's what my answer is about still. I guess it might be wrong in a sense that, I should give more warnings on the preferred approach. Personally, I used it to print a CLI instruction that _can_ be copy-pasted by the user to a terminal (again something that you should never really encourage, to be fair).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, seems that it is not possible to ever preserve the quotes, but for the issue I was dealing with it wasn't necessary.

I have a [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) function that will search down folder recursively and [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) for a string, the problem is passing a string that has spaces, such as "find this string". Passing this to the Bash script will then take the base argument $n and pass it to grep, this has grep believing these are different arguments. The way I solved this by using the fact that when you quote Bash to call the function it groups the items in the quotes into a single argument. I just needed to decorate that argument with quotes and pass it to the grep command.

If you know what argument you are receiving in bash that needs quotes for its next step you can just decorate with with quotes.