# Shell quoting with quotation marks in bash

Tags: bash, escaping, printf

I want to implement a bash function that runs its arguments as a command, while (maybe optionally) printing the command before. Think of an installation script or test runner script.

Just using

```
function run () {
    echo "Running $@"
    "$@"
}
```

would not allow me to distinguish a call from `run foo arg1 arg2` and `run foo "arg1 arg2"`, so I need to properly escape arguments.

My best shot so far is

```
function run () {
    echo -n "Running"
    printf " %q" "$@"
    echo
    "$@"
}
```

Which works:

```
$ run echo "one_argument" "second argument" argument\"with\'quotes
Running echo one_argument second\ argument argument\"with\'quotes
one_argument second argument argument"with'quotes
```

but is not very elegant. How can I achieve an output of

```
$ run echo "one_argument" "second argument" argument\"with\'quotes
Running echo one_argument "second argument" "argument\"with'quotes"
one_argument second argument argument"with'quotes
```

i.e. how can I make `printf` to put quotation marks around arguments that need quoting, and properly escape quotes therein, so that the output can be copy’n’pasted correctly?

Comment: Could you just put quotation marks around _all_ arguments, not just the ones that need it? You could just escape double quotes around all arguments, as shown here: tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_03.html

Comment: That would be ugly, and would be incorrect if the the argument contained a quotation mark. For debugging output that is not so severe, but I’d still like the output to be correct.

Comment: Ah, I see. My knowledge of BASH is not sufficient to help past that, sorry.

Comment: Take a look at this: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/1669493/1744633](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1669493/1744633)

Comment: Also doesn’t escape quotes inside the argument. I guess I should elaborate my question.

Answer (score 3):

This will quote everything:

```
run() {
    printf "Running:"
    for arg; do 
        printf ' "%s"' "${arg//\"/\\\"}"
    done
    echo
    "$@"
}
run echo "one_argument" "second argument" argument\"with\'quotes
```

```
Running: "echo" "one_argument" "second argument" "argument\"with'quotes"
one_argument second argument argument"with'quotes
```

This version only quotes arguments containing double quotes or whitespace:

```
run() {
    local fmt arg
    printf "Running:"
    for arg; do
        [[ $arg == *[\"[:space:]]* ]] && fmt=' "%s"' || fmt=" %s" 
        printf "$fmt" "${arg//\"/\\\"}"
    done
    echo
    "$@"
}
run echo "one_argument" "second argument" argument\"with\'quotes
```

```
Running: echo one_argument "second argument" "argument\"with'quotes"
one_argument second argument argument"with'quotes
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's an elegant solution to what you want, because `"$@"` is handled by `bash` before any command ever gets to see it. You'll have to manually re-construct the command-line:

```
#!/bin/bash

function run() {
  echo -n "Running:"
  for arg in "$@"; do
    arg="$(sed 's/"/\\&/g' <<<$arg)"
    [[ $arg =~ [[:space:]\\\'] ]] && arg=\"arg\"
    echo -n " $arg"
  done
  echo ""

  "$@"
}

run "$@"
```

Output:

```
$ ./test.sh echo arg1 "arg 2" "arg3\"with'other\'\nstuff"
Running: echo arg1 "arg 2" "arg3\"with'other\'\nstuff"
arg1 arg 2 arg3"with'other\'\nstuff
```

Note that there are some corner cases where you won't get the exact input command line. This happens when you pass arguments that `bash` expands before passing them on, e.g.:

```
$ ./test.sh echo foo'bar'baz
Running: echo foobarbaz
foobarbaz
$ ./test.sh echo "foo\\bar"
Running: echo "foo\bar"
foobar
```

Comment: This looks very similar to [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668649/how-to-keep-quotes-in-args/1669493#1669493) linked by @MohammadJavadNaderi in the comments; it does not seem to handle quoting special characters such as `"` itself.

Comment: You can't `shift` the arguments away -- you won't be able to execute the command after printing it! Also, your regular expression will match one of the characters {"a", "c", "e", "p", "s", ":"} -- you need `[[:space:]]`

Comment: @glennjackman That's what I get for insufficient testing. Thanks for the heads up. Fixed.