# passing string with spaces from shell to java

Tags: java, shell

I am doing a simple job of passing my java arguments from shell to java and one of the arguments happen to have spaces.

> ./test.ksh -test param1 param2 "\"param3 with spaces\""

code in test.ksh

```
if [ "$1" = "-test" ]
then
   echo "Test"
   SCRIPT_ARG="${*}"
   echo "${SCRIPT_ARG}"
fi

java -jar test.jar ${SCRIPT_ARG}
```

But inside the java code the third parameter is being read and printed as

> "param3

it seems very simple, but short of ideas here

Comment: I have no problems passing strings with spaces directly to java: `java <classname> "abc def" "ghi"`

Comment: This is actually trickier than it looks, but it's answered here (NOT the accepted answer; look at the second or other answers): http://stackoverflow.com/a/8723305/719547

Comment: Try `java -jar test.jar "param with spaces"`
Or just enclose ${SCRIPT_ARG} in spaces:
`java -jar test.jar "${SCRIPT_ARG}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments are a list of strings, but you concatenate them into a single string that you then re-split on spaces.

Instead, don't concatenate them and instead process them as a list of strings:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

if [ "$1" = "-test" ]
then
   echo "Test"
   script_arg=( "${@}" )
   for i in "${script_arg[@]}"
   do
     echo "One of the arguments is: $i"
   done
fi

java -jar test.jar "${script_arg[@]}"
```

You should then run it with:

```
./test.ksh -test param1 param2 "param3 with spaces"
```

and not try to embed any more quotes.

Comment: You need to shift the `-test` arg off.

Comment: OP doesn't do or mention that, but maybe.

Comment: You're right, but I think OP meant that too. Anyway, see the dup link in my question comment; this is one of the answers there too.

Comment: Thanks for your response, so the key was "${script_arg[@]}", including each param in quotes at this point.
if I pass quotes in quotes (with escaping) why does java does not accept it as a quotes argument?

Comment: Quotes are shell syntax that ksh uses to fill in your Java program's `String[] args`. Java doesn't know about or interpret quotes. If you call `main(new String[] { "foo", "\"bar", "baz\"" })` you'd obviously also see 3 elements in the array, and not 2. The literal quotes don't matter and aren't reinterpreted.

Comment: @thatotherguy" makes perfect sense..thanks!..god bless you