# Bash strips quotes passed to java command line application

Tags: java, bash, picocli

I have a java command line application written using Picocli, and I am trying to pass to it a string parameter, but every time I try the bash strips the quotes and I end with three parameters.

```
javaCLI install "Extras lib v0.1.4.cpkg"
```

This is the output I receive in bash

```
positional parameter at index 0..* (package_file) should be specified only once
Usage: javaCLI install package_file
```

I tried using escape single (\') and double quotes (\"), escape spaces (\ ), even both single and double quotes (with and without ) but none of them work. The easy solution is to rename the package to extras_lib_v0.1.4.cpkg but I will have the same problem with other methods.

Comment: What is "javaCli"? A shell script you wrote yourself?

Comment: `javaCli install Extras*.cpkg` (If you can't beat 'em, join 'em). You can also try `find . -name "*.cpkg" -exec javaCli install {} \;`

Comment: do you want the double quotes to be passed to the java app, or are you just using those as delimiters?

Comment: I bet the problem is not in `bash` but in `javaCli`, so I join the question of the first comment: what is `javaCli`?

Comment: The error message is correct and accurate if not helpful. "Usage: javaCLI" you have used `javaCli`. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: javaCLI is a custom application written in Java using picocli.CommandLine library. What @Elliot suggested helped with methods using paths to files but not with methods using strings. Is this something can be worked around or should I ask the author to fix the issue?

Comment: The explanation "javaCLI is a custom application written in Java ..." is very high-level. More specific details would be useful to help solve this issue. It would be useful to know if `javaCLI` a is bash script, or a native image compiled with GraalVM, or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that `javaCLI` is a wrapper script that calls `java` and that the quotes are stripped by this wrapper script.

The error message "positional parameter at index 0..* (package_file) should be specified only once" tells me that the `install` subcommand has a single `@Parameters`-annotated String field named `package_file`, so it expects only a single positional parameter, but was invoked with multiple parameters.

You can confirm that the java application incorrectly received 4 arguments instead of the desired 2 by setting system property `-Dpicocli.trace=DEBUG`. This will cause picocli to print some details, including exactly what command line args it received.

I am guessing that the `javaCLI` wrapper script passes the parameters like this:

```
java -cp myjar.jar:picocli-4.2.0.jar com.xxx.MainClass $@
```

If that is the case it may be possible to fix the issue by ensuring the quotes are preserved when passing arguments to the `java` executable. Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/39463371/1446916 for the idea of using [printf](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtin-Commands) to preserve the quotes:

```
# attempt to ensure each argument keeps its original quoting
ARGS=$( printf "%q " "$@" )

java -cp myjar.jar:picocli-4.2.0.jar com.xxx.MainClass ${ARGS}
```

If my guesses are incorrect please provide more details in the question.

Comment: @pyserial-killer I updated my answer with a new idea: use `printf` to preserve quotes when invoking `java`.