# Escape single quotes in shell invocation

Tags: bash, systemd

I'm trying to write a [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) service file without resorting to using an external script.

I need to query an [SQLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) database and write the contents to a file. But my query uses double quotes. I need to wrap the query in single quotes and since systemd doesn't use a shell, I need to manually use one. So how do I accomplish this?

```
ExecStart=sh -c 'sqlite3 dbfile.db 'SELECT "The db value is: "||value FROM table' > output.log'
```

I have tried escaping the inner single quotes, but for some reason that doesn't work.

Comment: Put your command in a separate script, and set its name to ExecStart value

Comment: i am not sure, but does `echo 'cmd str1' "cmd str2"...etc | sh ` work? you can join multiple strings wrapped in varied quotes. or even otherwise, regular escaping with `\ ` should work, right?

Comment: Related: *[How to escape single quotes within single quoted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/)*

Comment: Though there is probably a specific canonical question for this somewhere. This question *must* be a duplicate.

Comment: Possible lead: *[How can I keep quotes in Bash arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668649/how-to-keep-quotes-in-bash-arguments)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ExecStart=sh -c 'sqlite3 dbfile.db '\''SELECT "The db value is: "||value FROM table'\'' > output.log'
```

I used to use [MySQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) and double quotes work as well. You can also give it a shot:

```
ExecStart=sh -c 'sqlite3 dbfile.db "SELECT \"The db value is: \"||value FROM table" > output.log'
```

Comment: Can you explain what `'\''` means? I understand the escaping, but it's doubled?

Comment: The first `'` actually closed the command, let `\'` escape single quote out of the whole quotes, and the last `'` concats the rest of command. A clearer example: `'This is '\'' escaped single quote'` consists of `'This is '` + `\'` + `' escaped single quote'`.