# How to escape single quotes while setting aliases

Tags: bash

I want to create an alias of this command:

```
find . -name '*.sh' -exec chmod a+x '{}' \;
```

And I am not able to escape the single quotes while setting the alias:

```
alias mx='find . -name '*.sh' -exec chmod a+x '{}' \;'
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/bash-escaping-single-quotes-inside-of-single-quoted-strings when you need double quotes and single quotes

Comment: The canonical is probably *[How to escape single quotes within single quoted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/)* (2009. 26 answers. 1380 votes). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings/16605140#16605140) for a relatively simple syntax.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could just use double quotes:

```
alias mx="find . -name '*.sh' -exec chmod a+x {} \;"
```

Also, the single quotes `'` around the `{}` are not necessary.

Comment: Do you also need to escape the backslash since you're using double quotes?  `"... chmod a+x {} \\\;"`

Comment: Works well. FYI, when I create an alias like that, (GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)) it automatically changes the double-quotes into single quotes, and converts any single quotes into `'\''` . So the mx alias above becomes `alias mx='find . -name '\''*.sh'\'' -exec chmod a+x {} \;'` all by itself, similar to Mark's answer (also good).

Answer (score 14):

You want a function, not an alias.

```
function mx {
  find . -name '*.sh' -exec chmod a+x '{}' \;
}
```

This will have the same effect an alias would have had, avoids any "creative solutions" to make work, and is more flexible should you ever need the flexibility.  A good example of this flexibility, in this case, is enabling the user to specify the directory to search, and default to the current directory if no directory is specified.

```
function mx {
  if [ -n $1 ]; then
    dir=$1
  else
    dir='.'
  fi
  find $dir -name '*.sh' -exec chmod a+x '{}' \;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

The other answers contain better solutions in this (and most) cases, but might you for some reason really want to escape `'`, you can do `'"'"'` which actually ends the string, adds a `'` escaped by `"` and starts the string again.

```
alias mx='find . -name '"'"'*.sh'"'"' -exec chmod a+x {} \;'
```

There is more information at *[How to escape single quotes within single quoted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/bash-escaping-single-quotes-inside-of-single-quoted-strings)*.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
alias mx=$'find . -name \'*.sh\' -exec chmod a+x \'{}\' \\;'
```

From `man bash`:

Words of the form $'string' are treated specially. The word expands to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard. Backslash  escape sequences, if present, are decoded as follows:

```
\\     backslash
\'     single quote
\"     double quote
\n     new line
...
```

See example:

```
echo $'aa\'bb'
```