# How do I properly escape data for a Makefile?

Tags: bash, makefile, escaping

I'm dynamically generating `config.mk` with a bash script which will be used by a Makefile. The file is constructed with:

```
cat > config.mk <<CFG
SOMEVAR := $value_from_bash1
ANOTHER := $value_from_bash2
CFG
```

How do I ensure that the generated file really contains the contents of `$value_from_bash*`, and not something expanded / interpreted? I probably need to escape `$` to `$$` and `\` to `\\`, but are there other characters that needs to be escaped? Perhaps there is a special literal assignment I've not heard of?

Spaces seems to be troublesome too:

```
$ ls -1
a b
a
$ cat Makefile
f := a b
default_target:
    echo "$(firstword $(wildcard ${f}))"
$ make
a
```

If I use `f := a\ b` it works (using quotes like `f := 'a b'` did not work either, makefile just treats it as a regular character)

Comment: What version of Make are you using?

Comment: This is not a Makefile question but a bash one. I think you know how you want your makefile look like , so your problem is escaping things in your bash here-document. Have a look at this http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html

Comment: No, I'm not asking how to replace strings in bash, but what to do for getting strings from bash in a Makefile without modifying the meaning (e.g. if `echo "$var"` shows `"whatever \'`, the same should be displayed in the Makefile)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Okay, it turned out that Makefiles need little escaping for itself, but the commands which are executed by the shell interpreter *need* to be escaped.

Characters which have a special meaning in Makefile and that need to be escaped are:

- sharp (`#`, comment) becomes `\#`
- dollar (`$`, begin of variable) becomes `$$`

Newlines cannot be inserted in a variable, but to avoid breaking the rest of the Makefile, prepend it with a backslash so the line break will be ignored.

Too bad a backslash itself cannot be escaped (`\\` will still be `\\` and not `\` as you might expect). This makes it not possible to put a literal slash on the end of a string as it will either eat the newline or the hash of a following comment. A space can be put on the end of the line, but that'll also be put in the variable itself.

The recipe itself is interpreted as a shell command, without any fancy escaping, so you've to escape data yourself, just imagine that you're writing a shellscript and inserting the variables from other files. The strategy here would be putting the variables between single quotes and escape only `'` with `'\''` (close the string, insert a literal `'` and start a new string). Example: `mornin' all` becomes `'morning'\'' all'` which is equivalent to `"morning' all"`.

The firstword+wildcard issue is caused by the fact that filenames with spaces in them are treated as separate filenames by `firstword`. Furthermore, `wildcard` expands escapes using `\` so `x\ y` is matches as one word, `x y` and not two words.

Comment: backtick as well :)

Comment: Related blog post which shows that `$` in bash must be escaped as `$$` in make: https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/k3kjqxtppx-escape-dollar-sign-on-makefiles

Comment: and `%` becomes `%%`

Answer (score 10):

It seems that the **full** answer to this question is found **nowhere on the internet**, so I finally sat down and figured it out for the Windows case.

Specifically, the "Windows case" refers to file names that are valid in Windows, meaning that they do **not** contain the characters `\`, `/`, `*`, `?`, `"`, `^`, `<`, `>`, `|`, or line breaks. It also means `\` and `/` are both considered valid directory separators for the purposes of Make.

An example will clear it up better than I can explain. Basically, if you are trying to match this file path:

```
Child\a$b  {'}(a.o#$@,&+=~`),[].c
```

Then you have to write these rules:

```
all: Child\\a$$b\\\ \\\ {'}(a.o\#$$@,&+=~`),[].o

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) '$(subst ','"'"',$(subst \,,$(subst \\,/,$+)))'
```

Stare at it for a long time and it'll sort of start making some remote sense.

This works in my MSYS2 environment, so I presume it is correct.

Comment: That substitution pattern looks odd, is that syntactically valid? It seems to replace `'` by `'"'"'` (after replacing `\` by `/`), is that correct? Oh, basically you are replacing `'` by `'`, then a quoted literal `"'"`, and then continue the single quotes which start before and after the argument. Do you have some references for this escaping?

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Yup, [http://stackoverflow.com/a/1250279/541686](here). However, that's by far the easiest aspect of this problem. The real difficulty is not messing up spaces and other characters, and I think my answer still fails in some cases... I'll update it when I have a better one.

Comment: Ah yes, that is sh-style escaping, not necessarily for Windows commands. IIRC `^` is the escape character used in Windows (batch scripts).

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Actually this isn't for batch scripts, it's for sh-style escapes... but on Windows (MSYS2) rather than Linux. Sorry for the confusion, the main reason I posted the answer was that I was looking for it myself, not so much that I thought it'd help your case necessarily.

Comment: Yeah it works, but the prerequisite is considered not exist and redundant compile will take place.

Answer (score 2):

1. I don't see how that makefile can work as you say. A pattern rule cannot be the default.

   You're missing a `$` in `$(wildcard ...)`, so I think you haven't posted what you're really testing.

   You should escape newlines too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've indeed made a typo when making the example. Is it enough to escape just newlines, spaces, dollars and backslashes?

Comment: @Lekensteyn, I think so. But you might want to rethink your design; Make was never really intended for hard-core string manipulation.

Comment: The variables are in fact file paths. Usually, these do not contain special characters like newlines (which I'll therefore ignore), `$` (but you'll never know for sure). Possible special characters which need to be taken care of are `"`, `'` and spaces.

Comment: could you improve the answer by summarizing the list of characters to be escaped?

Answer (score 1):

None of the other answers worked for me for a broader set of arbitrary one-line strings, which might include quotes (single or double), backslashes, hashtags, and other, and needs to be passed to a shell command as an argument.

I went with this, which seems to work for input that does not contain a dollar sign (or newline).

```
ESCAPED:=$(subst $\',$\'$\"$\'$\"$\',$(INPUT))
```

For example, if my entire Makefile is:

```
$(info Input: $(INPUT))

ESCAPED:=$(subst $\',$\'$\"$\'$\"$\',$(INPUT))

run_shell_cmd_with_input_argument:
    echo '${ESCAPED}'
```

then the following invocation:

```bash
make INPUT="1,2\"3\'23'"'!#()*%'
```

will print the following:

```
Input: 1,2"3\'23'!#()*%
Escaped: 1,2"3\'"'"'23'"'"'!#()*%
echo '1,2"3\'"'"'23'"'"'!#()*%'
1,2"3\'23'!#()*%
```

How it works:

1. The shell invocation uses single-quotes to ensure that nothing is interpreted inside the quoted string
2. Now we just need to worry about escaping single-quotes
3. Since we can't directly escape single-quotes inside a string that is quoted with single-quotes, we indirectly do so by replacing each single-quote with '"'"'. That way, when surrounded by single-quotes a value of `a'b`, when quoted, becomes `'a'"'"'b'` which is suitable for use in a shell command

```
$(subst $\',$\'$\"$\'$\"$\',$(INPUT))
# ^^^^^                              substitute command
#       ^^^                          replace ' chars
#           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^         with '"'"'
```