# How to properly escape hash in Android.mk?

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk, ndk-build

I am using `-Werror` flag to treat all warnings as errors in my code. However, I would like compile warnings issued from code to still be treated as warnings. A GCC option for this is `-Wno-error=cpp` which works correctly, however clang option is `-Wno-error=#warnings` which I don't know how to pass to `clang` from `Android.mk`.

I've tried this:

```
ifeq "$(findstring clang,$(NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION))" "clang"
    LOCAL_CFLAGS += -Wno-error=#warnings
endif
```

and this (as suggested in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7860705/213057)):

```
ifeq "$(findstring clang,$(NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION))" "clang"
    LOCAL_CFLAGS += -Wno-error=\#warnings
endif
```

However, both versions treat `#` as beginning of comment and `ndk-build` passes `-Wno-error=` to compiler (i.e. everything after `=` is ignored) - I inspected that with `ndk-build -n`.

I even tried

```
ifeq "$(findstring clang,$(NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION))" "clang"
    LOCAL_CFLAGS += -Wno-error=\\#warnings
endif
```

which produces `-Wno-error=\` compiler flag.

How to properly pass this compiler flag to clang from `Android.mk` file?

I am using NDK r12b.

EDIT:
I even tried this:

```
ifeq "$(findstring clang,$(NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION))" "clang"
    VAR=\#warnings
    $(info VAR is '$(VAR)')
    LOCAL_CFLAGS += -Wno-error=$(VAR)
endif
```

and `ndk-build` first outputs message `VAR is '#warnings'` yet compiler arguments contain `-Wno-error=`. This is obviously an NDK issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -Wno-error=\#warnings
```

is almost there. But to get `make` to treat the `\` as escaping the `#`
it needs to be in quoted context.

**Makefile**

```
CXX := clang++

CXXFLAGS += "-Wno-error=\#warnings"

hello: HelloWorld.o
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^
```

Build and run:

```
$ make && ./hello
clang++ "-Wno-error=#warnings"   -c -o HelloWorld.o HelloWorld.cpp
clang++ -o hello HelloWorld.o
Hello World
```

Comment: Tried that. In the command line ends up `"-Wno-error=`. This appears to be a NDK issue, not a makefile problem. I've reported the issue [here](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/161).