# How to use awk in Makefile?

Tags: shell, awk, makefile

I hava a Makefile which needs to extract some information from a textfile `someText.txt by using awk. Here is an example:

Executing awk on my textfile manually in the console works pretty fine:

```
$ cat someText.txt | awk '/Total number:/ {print $NF}'
$ 42
```

But using it in my makefile does not work:

```
MYVAR=$(shell cat someText.txt | awk '/Total number:/ {print $NF}')
all:
    @echo Count: $(MYVAR)
```

The output is: `Count:`

But I would suggest the output is `Count: 42`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly escape data for a Makefile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654386/how-do-i-properly-escape-data-for-a-makefile)

Comment: As an aside, you also want to avoid the [useless use of `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html)

Comment: TL;DR you need to double every `$$` which should be passed through to the shell.

Comment: triple is alluding to this... `awk '/Total number:/ {print $NF}' someText.txt`

Comment: Yes, thats it. I overlooked the dollar within the curly brackets. Using `{print $$NF}` works pretty fine.

Answer (score 5):

`MYVAR=$(shell cat someText.txt | awk '/Total number:/ {print $$NF}')`