# curl : working in command line but not in makefile

Tags: curl, makefile

very simple command in my makefile

```
something:
    curl "the_verified_url" -O "full_path_to_file"
```

gives me

`curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
Makefile:35: recipe for target 'something' failed
make: *** [savetradesdbscheme] Error 3`

but running it plainly in the cmd works like a charm. What gives ?

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654386/how-do-i-properly-escape-data-for-a-makefile) will help you.  Also please provide [mcve] in your question.

Comment: Agreed that your example is not sufficient.  Given what you've shown there's no way you'll get that error, so obviously what you're really doing is different from what you've shown here in some significant way.  Obviously we can't guess what that difference might be.  At least look at the command line that make is printing and check it against the command line in your recipe.