# Using svn setprop with a shell script variable in the property value

Tags: svn, shell

I want to use a variable in a `svn setprop svn:externals` command in a shell script.

The path is set as a variable, and works fine:

```
LOCALPATH="/some/path"
TARGETFOLDER="folder"
svn propset svn:externals 'dir -r100 http://svn.example.com/repos/trunk' $LOCALPATH/$TARGETFOLDER/externals
```

However, if I try to use a variable for the revision number, it doesn't work:

```
LOCALPATH="/some/path"
TARGETFOLDER="folder"
REV="100"
PROP="'dir -r$REV http://svn.example.com/repos/trunk'"
echo $PROP
svn propset svn:externals $PROP $LOCALPATH/$TARGETFOLDER/externals
```

The `PROP` variable is echoed correctly, but the `propset` doesn't work. I always get the following error:

```
svn: Cannot specify revision for setting versioned property 'svn:externals'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try removing the single quotes around `PROP` value.

Comment: I need to wrap the property in single quotes for the `propset` command to work. If I use `svn:external '$PROP' $LOCALPATH` on the final line, `$PROP` is treated as a string literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem with escaping single quotes in shell. See [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/bash-escaping-single-quotes-inside-of-single-quoted-strings) explained. Playing around with your case found the following combination working:

```
....
PROP="dir -r$REV http://.../trunk"
svn propset svn:externals ''"$PROP"'' $LOCALPATH/$TARGETFOLDER/externals
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not find anything wrong with your script. I experience the same issue, though.

If you're blocked by this script, you may consider **using an external file** to set your property:

```
LOCALPATH="/some/path"
TARGETFOLDER="folder"
REV="100"
PROP="'dir -r$REV http://svn.example.com/repos/trunk'"
echo $PROP > svn.externals
svn propset svn:externals -F svn.externals
# rm svn.externals
```

---

*Note:* Instead of echoing commands when you debug a shell script you can use the xtrace flag:

```
sh -x myscript.sh
```

It will output each executed command prepended with with a `+`.

Comment: Thanks. Can I remove the `svn.externals` file after setting the property, or is it referenced by subversion ?

Comment: Yes. Some people like to check this file into svn as well, but I think you shouldn't, as propget would give you the value back.