# How can I escape a single quote in a single-quote string in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, escaping

I want to display a string in Bash like this:

```
I'm a student
```

Of course you can do it like this:

```
echo "I'm a student"
```

But how can I accomplish this while using single quotes around the string?

Comment: Sorry, there is no way to place a single quote in between single quotes. See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters on section `3.1.2.2 Single Quotes`

Comment: And that in a script, how do you do? `su -c '/etc/init.d/myservice start' -l myuser` (run by root)

Comment: The canonical is probably *[How to escape single quotes within single quoted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/)* (2009. 26 answers. 1380 votes). [An answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings/16605140#16605140) covers the same as the top answer here.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

```
echo 'I\'m a student'
```

does not work. But the following works:

```
echo $'I\'m a student'
```

From the man page of Bash:

> A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded
> by a backslash.
> .... 
> Words of the form **$'string'** are treated specially.  The word
> expands to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as
> specified by the ANSI C standard.

Comment: An uglier form is: `'I'"'"'m a student'

Comment: `echo $'I\'m a student!'` =>  `!': event not found`, this is not a *real* single quoted string which, in bash, should protect from any interpretation.

Comment: @regilero What versions have problems with this?  I don't see that error in bash 4.1.2.

Comment: @sappjw OS X bash: `$ bash --version`

`GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

Comment: And this kind of stuff is why I use Python as a replacement for Bash scripts now.

Comment: re: `os/x` bash:  this answer works for me in bash on same version  `bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

Comment: @regilero according to the manual, it is `The expanded result is single-quoted, as if the dollar sign had not been present.` https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting

Comment: Just in case, `dash` and `ash` (i.e. common alias for `/bin/sh`) does not support `$'` or Bash's ANSI-C Quoting as of 2023 since it's not POSIX I believe.

Answer (score 77):

The "ugly" solution [mentioned by Glenn Jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254120/how-can-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-a-single-quote-string-in-bash#comment10168173_8254156) should actually be listed as a top level answer. It works well and is actually beautiful in some situations.

```
'I'"'"'m a student'
```

This ends the single quoted string after `I` then immediately starts a double quoted string containing a single quote and then starts another single quoted string. Bash then concatenates all contiguous strings into one.

Beautiful!

Comment: I think our definitions of beauty differ somewhat.. ;)

Comment: Strictly speaking, it doesn't answer the question of how to escape a single quote inside a single-quoted string ;-)

Comment: the underlying most common problematic is wanting to go "level n" on refactoring code. this does answer that demand. while the `$` does not necessarily have "+n" capacity. I'm not sure I'll have to test more. but it look to me like I'll be able to execute code that was already in single quotes stored into separate variables thanks to this.

Comment: Why not just `echo I"'"m a student`?

Answer (score 37):

The example below works because the escaped single quote `\'` is technically between two single-quoted arguments

```
echo 'I'\''m a student'
```

Comment: This seems to be the best answer. I guess it's not highly voted cause it's been posted several years after the previous answers.

Comment: Much better than the answer above and far less confusing!

Comment: on  scp gives error unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''

Answer (score 0):

Another way to workaround is to use `printf` instead `echo` and escape the required single quote with \x27:

```
printf 'I\x27m a student!\n'
```

Answer (score -5):

I propose

`echo "I'm a student"`

like in other languages.

Comment: Doesn't the question exclude this? *Of course you can do it like this `echo "I'm a student"` But how to accomplish this while using single quote around the string ?*