# Replace string in ALT attribute using SED

Tags: bash, sed

I have an HTML file that contains the following ALT attribute:

```
alt="Hello I am <nobr>Please&nbsp;replace&nbsp;me</nobr> and I'm cool"
```

I need to use SED in a bash script to replace the above line with:

```
alt="Hello I am Please replace me and I'm cool"
```

How do I only target only the  tag inside a alt attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `sed` answer would be:

```
 sed -E '/alt=/{:a s/(<nobr>)(.*)&nbsp;(.*)(<\/nobr>)/\1\2 \3\4/;ta; s/<nobr>(.*)<\/nobr>/\1/}'
```

Explanation:

- `/alt=/` only change lines containing `alt=`
- `s/(<nobr>)(.*)&nbsp;(.*)(<\/nobr>)/\1\2 \3\4/` replace one `&nbsp;` with space
- `ta` repeat if succesful; that is, jump to `a`
- `s/<nobr>(.*)<\/nobr>/\1/` finally remove the `<nobr>` and `</nobr>`

**Added:** Because `sed` is greedy, this script will *fail* if there are two `</nobr>`'s in the line. While there are work-arounds--see ishahak\s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19683076/318716) to [Non greedy (reluctant) regex matching in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-reluctant-regex-matching-in-sed) --it becomes a pain.

In any case, this answer is already overkill as it is, since the OP found that a much simpler solution sufficed for their needs; see comment below.

Comment: Since I wanted to remove all the nobr tags and the nbsps, I went this route: `sed -i "/alt=/{
     s|<nobr>||g;
     s|</nobr>||g;
     s|&nbsp;| |g;
    }" "$projectPath/$htmlfile"`

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with `awk` then try following:(taking all strings whic you want to substitute in variables of `awk`)

```
awk -v val="<nobr>" -v val1="&nbsp;" -v val2="</nobr>" '
/^alt/{
  gsub(val," ")
  gsub(val1," ")
  gsub(val2," ")
}
1'  Input_file
```

OR

```
awk -v val="<nobr>" -v val1="&nbsp;" -v val2="</nobr>" '
/^alt/{
  gsub(val"|"val1"|"val2," ")
}
1'  Input_file
```

Append `> temp_file  && mv temp_file Input_file` to above codes, in case you want to make the changes into Input_file itself.

Comment: Op needs to only replace the tags that are inside in `alt`

Comment: @Gioconda, sure, edited it now, thank you for letting me know.

Comment: I'm ok with AWK. Will try that! Thank you for suggesting!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hamfisted way of doing it:

```
% sed $'s#alt="Hello I am <nobr>Please&nbsp;replace&nbsp;me</nobr> and I\'m cool"#alt="Hello I am Please replace me and I\'m cool"#' < file.html
```

My suggestion would be to not parse html using shell tools - it will only lead to tears and frustration. Use python's [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) module instead.

Comment: btw, see this answer for what that extraneous '$' is doing in there.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254120/how-to-escape-a-single-quote-in-single-quote-string-in-bash