# Do zsh or bash have quotes that are convenient for English text?

Tags: bash, escaping, quotes, zsh

If I use single quotes, words with apostrophes ("don't") are annoying to escape:

```
'Don'"'"'t do that'
```

If I use double quotes, dollar signs and exclamation points trip it up:

```
"It cost like \$1000\!"
```

Is there another kind of quoting I can use?

**edit**: I should also add that I would like to pass this string directly as a command line argument, rather than storing it in a variable. To this end I tried, using DigitalRoss's solution,

```
$ echo "$(cat << \EOF 
Don't $worry be "happy".
EOF)"
```

but get

```
dquote cmdsubst>
```

after hitting enter :/ . So at this point ZyX's suggestion of `setopt rcquotes` looks to be the most convenient.

Comment: the last `EOF` needs to be on a line by itself, no other characters. Put the close parenthesis on the next line.

Comment: @glennjackman I get the same result.

Comment: Hmm, the shell is waiting for the single quote to be matched.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With zsh you may do

```
setopt rcquotes
```

. Then ASCII apostrophes are escaped just like this:

```
echo 'Don''t'
```

. Or setup your keymap to be able to enter UTF apostrophes, they have no issues with any kind of quotes (including none) in any shell:

```
echo 'Don’t'
```

. Third works both for zsh and bash:

```
echo $'Don\'t'
```

.

Neither first nor third can narrow down quote to a single character, but they are still less verbose for non-lengthy strings then heredocs suggested above. With zsh you can do this by using custom accept-line widget that will replace constructs like `'Don't'` with `'Don'\''t'`. Requires rather tricky regex magic that I can write only in perl; and is probably not the best idea as I can’t pretend I can cover all possible cases before they will hit. It won’t in any case touch any scripts.

Answer (score 4):

I like the direction [Zsolt Botykai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11621/zsolt-botykai) is going. Here is an example that works with any Posix shell. (I also verified that it survived its paste into the SO server.)

```
$ read -r x << \EOF
Don't $worry be "happy".
EOF
$ echo $x
Don't $worry be "happy".
```

The things that make this work;

- `-r` will make `\` not be magic
- the `\EOF` instead of just `EOF` makes `$` not be magic

Comment: Note that unless you remove them from `$IFS`, leading and trailing blanks will be stripped. Also, it only works for single-line text.

Comment: I believe if you single quote `'EOF'`, it has the effect of single-quoting the whole text: `read -r x << 'EOF'`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to assign a quoted text to a variable, you still can use heredocs, like (and it can be a multiline text too):

```
read -r -d '' VAR <<'ENDOFVAR'
This "will be" a 'really well' escaped text. Or won't.
ENDOFVAR
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash syntax `$'string'` is another quoting mechanism which allows ANSI C-like escape sequences and do expansion to single-quoted version.

```
$> echo $'Don\'t $worry be "happy".'
Don't $worry be "happy".
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16605140/149221 for more details.