# Escape a single quote in a shell variable

Tags: bash, shell

I wrote a Bash script to insert values to an [SQLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) database. The command is as follows:

```
sqlite3 ${db_name} "insert into ${table_name} (${column1},${column2}) values ('$f1','$f2');"
```

This command works fine until the `f1` variable contains a single quote:

```
# E.g., f1="I'm just kidding"
# The command reported an error:
Error: near "m": syntax error
```

How can we escape the single quote inside the variable?

Comment: you are aware of the possibility of [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) in this script.. yes ?

Comment: My recommendation? Use a programming language.

Comment: Hi @Oren, actually I am not good at SQL, I just made the script to automatically add entry by entry manually to the db

Comment: if this is for personal use only I guess its fine. but if there's even a chance of this script being used by other people, the way it is written now leaves your database vulnerable to attacks. the answer to this is input validation, which would be hell to hard to implement in a script. @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams 's recommendation is a good one in that case.

Comment: The canonical is probably *[How to escape single quotes within single quoted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/)* (2009. 26 answers. 1380 votes). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings/16605140#16605140) for a relatively simple syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To escape a single quote for SQL, you double it (https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q14):

```
$ f1="I'm just kidding"
$ echo "${f1//\'/''}"
I''m just kidding
$ f2="no single quotes"
$ echo "${f2//\'/''}"
no single quotes
```

So

```
sqlite3 ${db_name} "insert into ${table_name} (${column1},${column2}) values ('${f1//\'/''}','${f2//\'/''}');"
```

Answer (score 4):

From Bash, you can use ${varname//x/y} to replace all instances of x with y in the varname variable.

```
sqlite3 ${db_name} "insert into ${table_name} (${column1},${column2}) values ('${f1//\'/\'}','${f2//\'/\'}');"
```

will replace any ' with ' though @ignacioVazquez-Abrams has the best answer as the [PHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), [Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl), and [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) implementations all have modules to help sanitise input.

Comment: Hi @peteches, thank you for your answer. It returns "Bad substitution"

Comment: yeah sorry rushed it a bit and put the escaping backslash in the wrong place. Edited now so should work. if not your bash version may not support the replacement can't remember what version it came in on

Answer (score -1):

You could use **\**

```
f1="I\'m just kidding"
```

Comment: Hi JoaoBiriba, the `f1` variable is read from file, so it can be arbitrary string. Should we pre-process the file before execute the script?

Comment: so you can pre-process your file using sed for example: sed 's/<pattern>/<replacement>/'