# sqlite query from bash script, single quote breaks syntax

Tags: bash, sqlite, variables

I have following in bash script:

```
sqlite3 database.db "INSERT INTO tbl (col1,col2) VALUES ('\"$line\"','\"$stdout\"');"
```

,where `$line` variable isn't going to make any trouble, but my `$stdout`
variable is output from `whois $line`, so it contains many chars, one of them
being `'` which breaks the `sqlite3` syntax.

Is there some way I could **quote-escape** that variable, so that it passes well
in this query?

**EDIT**

Sorry, I found my solution here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/14340973/2434479.

Should I delete this question?

Comment: Yes. This is a pretty close match to that other question. I'm glad Stack Overflow solved your problem one way or the other.

Comment: As a side note, aren't you "over quoting" your SQL statement? Are those `\"` required?

Comment: No, they aren't, I corrected that in my script, but left them here untouched. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard SQL escape sequence for *simple quote* `'` is the *double simple quote* `''`.

Using bash pattern substitution, you may perform the necessary replacements:

```
sh$ DSQ="''"
sh$ stdout="I'm in a big'trouble"
sh$ echo "${stdout//\'/$DSQ}"
I''m in a big''trouble
```

In your specific case:

```
DSQ="''"
sqlite3 database.db \
    "INSERT INTO tbl (col1,col2) VALUES ('$line','${stdout//\'/$DSQ}');"
```