# Bash escaping quotes

Tags: bash, sed, scripting, automation

I am executing some commands in a screen over SSH. This works perfectly:

```
ssh myuser@mydomain.com "screen -list; screen -r -d -X -S myscreen stuff $'echo here\n'"
```

But now rather than echo, I am trying to run the sed command, which contains double quotes.

```
sed -i -r "s/(    host: )(\w+)/\1test/" file.yml
```

The double quotes are causing bash: syntax error near unexpected token `database_name:'

How do I properly escape the double quotes required for sed?

Comment: Why do you need double quotes? This should work with single quotes around your sed command. You don't have anything you want to expand in it.

Comment: Single quotes interfere with the single quotes around the stuff command. I am trying to replace echo here with the sed command.

Comment: You can "quote" single quotes inside other single quotes by using `'\''`.

Comment: @EtanReisner: Or `'"'"'` :-)

Comment: Try providing the remote commands in a here document to `ssh`, rather than as quoted command-line arguments. It will save you a level of quotes.

Comment: @choroba `echo 'foo "'" bar'` does not work. You could do that for the outer level double-quotes but not for the inner level single-quotes.

Comment: @EtanReisner: You can't escape single quotes inside single-quoted strings. The backslash is Just Another Character(tm). In this case, it works because it is a $'-d string, not a single-quoted string.

Comment: @rici Hm? `echo $'foo "'" bar'` doesn't seem to work for me (nor would I have expected it to). Perhaps I'm missing where `'"'"'` should be used here? The problem is that the OP needs a single quote *inside* the `$'`-quoted string *inside* the outer double-quoted string.

Comment: @etan: `echo $'foo\'bar'`  will work, but not `echo 'foo\'bar'`. The zipper idiom is `'"'"'` as in `echo 'foo'"'"'bar'`, but not with outer double-quoting.

Comment: @rici Ah, ok. I didn't realize `\'` worked in `$'` quoting. Fun, that. Yeah, `'"'"'` (man typing that is annoying) generally works but is complicated here... then again so is just about anything given the nesting/etc.

Comment: @Etan: I was referring to your comment «You can "quote" single quotes inside other single quotes»: that's not correct. You can't, unless the outer single quotes are really $-single-quotes. (Inside double quotes, `'"\'"'` would work, because the innermost `'` is unquoted at that point.)

Comment: @rici Yeah, that's why I used the scare quotes around "quote" there but yes... I probably should have just avoided the word altogether.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running shell command that has nested quotes via ssh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30234546/running-shell-command-that-has-nested-quotes-via-ssh)

Comment: I don't seem to be having any luck with here doc. The following results in -bash: line 2: END: command not found. `ssh myuser@mydomain.com <<'END' screen -list; screen -r -d -X -S myscreen stuff $'echo here\n' END`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the easiest way to do this is by breaking it up into two commands.

First send the command to the screen. Escape any double quotes in the *stuff* command with a backslash.

```
ssh myuser@mydomain.com 'screen -list; screen -r -d -X -S myscreen stuff "sed -i -r \"s/(    host: )(\w+)/\1test/\"" file.yml'
                        └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
                                                                         └──────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Then send a return to execute the command. Note the $ which makes it execute.

```
ssh myuser@mydomain.com "screen -list; screen -r -d -X -S myscreen stuff $'\n'"
                        └─────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
                                                                          └──┘
```