# Why does vagrant ssh -c ignore single quotes in command?

Tags: bash, vagrant, psql

I want to update a column of my database running in a VW (using `Vagrant`) with the host's IP.

To do this I want to use a bash script:

```
LOCAL_IP=$(ipconfig getifaddr en0)
SQL="vagrant ssh -c 'psql -U user -d mydatabase -h localhost -c \"update mytable set mycolumn = '$LOCAL_IP';\"'"
eval $SQL
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ".123"
LINE 1: update mytable set mycolumn = 123.123.123.123;
```

The ouput of the SQL vriable:

```
echo $SQL
vagrant ssh -c 'psql -U user -d mydatabase -h localhost -c "update mytable set mycolumn = '123.123.123.123';"'
```

When I call the psql command from `echo $SQL` in the vm everything is fine, but I don't have the host ip.

```
vagrant ssh
psql -U user -d mydatabase -h localhost -c "update mytable set mycolumn = '123.123.123.123';"
```

It looks like the `vagrant ssh -c` command would remove the single quotes around the IP. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Easiest way to reproduce my problem:

```
$ vagrant ssh -c 'echo "update table set column = 'test';" > bla.sql'
$ vagrant ssh
$ cat bla.sql
update table set column = test;
```

Comment: Have you tried scaping the double quotes and the simple quotes arround the LOCAL_IP?

Comment: Yes, I have, but that produces errors before it can do anything on the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20498919/5902456

It looks now like this:
`SQL="vagrant ssh -c 'psql -U user -d mydatabase -h localhost -c \"update mytable set mycolumn = '\''$LOCAL_IP'\'';\"'"`