# ssh remote command execution quoting and piping awk

Tags: bash, awk, ssh

I'm working on a script, that should find certain disks and add hostname to them.

I'm using this for 40 servers with a for loop in bash

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in myservers{1..40}
    do ssh user@$i findmnt -o SIZE,TARGET -n -l |
            grep '1.8T\|1.6T\|1.7T' | 
            sed 's/^[ \t]*//' |
            cut -d ' ' -f 2 |
            awk -v HOSTNAME=$HOSTNAME '{print HOSTNAME ":" $0}'; done | 
    tee sorted.log
```

can you help out with the quoting here? It looks like awk gets piped (hostname) from localhost, not the remote server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything after the first pipe is running locally, not on the remote server.

Try quoting the entire pipeline to have it run on the remote server:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for i in myservers{1..40}
    do ssh user@$i "findmnt -o SIZE,TARGET -n -l | 
        sed 's/^[ \t]*//' |
        cut -d ' ' -f 2 |
        awk -v HOSTNAME=\$HOSTNAME '{print HOSTNAME \":\" \$0}'" ;
done | tee sorted.log
```

Comment: ... alternatively, just replace `HOSTNAME=$HOSTNAME` with `HOSTNAME=$i` in your original script.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shorter version of your stuff:

```
findmnt -o SIZE,TARGET -n -l | 
awk -v HOSTNAME=$HOSTNAME '/M/{print HOSTNAME ":" $2}'
```

Applied to the above:

```
for i in myservers{1..40}
    do ssh user@$i   bash -c ' 
            findmnt -o SIZE,TARGET -n -l | 
              awk -v HOSTNAME=$HOSTNAME '"'"'/M/{print HOSTNAME ":" $2}'"'"' '
         done | 
    tee sorted.log
```

see: [How to escape the single quote character in an ssh / remote bash command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498599/how-to-escape-the-single-quote-character-in-an-ssh-remote-bash-command)