# Problem with quotations when executing psql query over ssh

Tags: ssh, command-line, command-line-arguments, psql

I would like to execute a psql query through ssh directly from local machine.

In remote machine, the command works fine:

```
psql -U USER -d DATABASE -c "select A,B,C from TABLE where A='string1';"
```

Now, when using:

```
ssh user@host "psql -U USER -d DATABASE -c "select A,B,C from TABLE where A='string1';""
```

I get errors such as:

```
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "A,B,C" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "from" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "TABLE" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "where" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "A=string1" ignored
```

I understand that the problem is due to the quotes as the following command in the local machine works fine:

```
ssh user@host "psql -U USER -d DATABASE -c '\l'"
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking cues from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20498858/13981285), the following command works:

```
ssh user@host 'psql -U USER -d DATABASE -c "select A,B,C from TABLE where A='"'"'string1'"'"';'
```