# How do I properly quote this bash pipeline for watch?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I've built up this pipeline:

```
echo "scale=2;$(cat io | grep wchar | awk '{print $2}')/(1024^3)" | bc
```

Now I'm trying to `watch` it. My knowledge of Bash is really ad-hoc, and so I'm not having success. Tried things like:

```
watch echo "scale=2;$(cat io | grep wchar | awk '{print $2}')/(1024^3)" | bc # I understand why this fails

watch 'echo "scale=2;$(cat io | grep wchar | awk '{print $2}')/(1024^3)" | bc' # Not enough bash understanding to understand why this fails
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Sample output from `cat io` is

```
rchar: 36713294562
wchar: 36788363400
syscr: 27050
syscw: 2314540
read_bytes: 36709928960
write_bytes: 0
cancelled_write_bytes: 0
```

Comment: If you look carefully at the syntax highlighting on your second try you can see why it fails.

Comment: The simplest solution is to put everything in a script, and use that as the argument to `watch`.

Comment: Kevin: I saw that hint, actually! And so I tried replacing the single quotes around {print $2} with double quotes. No luck. I believe the single quote in awk is a token that's non-equivalent to the double quote

Comment: Barmar: That's a good call.

Comment: @dimadima To address a comment to another user, put `@` before their name and a space after it (as I've done here, although it's not necessary when addressing the OP). Otherwise they won't be notified of the comment.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. Didn't think that was strictly necessary. Will do so from now on.

Comment: Nesting quotes is really messy, putting it in a script generally solves the problem.

Comment: @Barmar: yeah... I'm on that now. Clearly that's the best way to go. Would love to see an answer anyway, if possible, just to learn what I'm missing.

Comment: It is not a direct answer to your question but using "cut -f2 -d:" instead of "awk '{print $2}'" may solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is about the single quotes for awk, you could fix it by escaping single quotes.

```
watch 'echo "scale=2;$(cat io | grep wchar | awk '"'"'{print $2}'"'"')/(1024^3)" | bc'
```

It is all about how to escaping single quotes inside single quotes, there is a good explanation ["BASH, escaping single-quotes inside of single-quoted strings"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/bash-escaping-single-quotes-inside-of-single-quoted-strings)

Answer (score 3):

Try having `watch` invoke the shell:

```
watch sh -c 'echo "scale=2;$(awk '/wchar/ {print $2}' io)/(1024^3)" | bc'
```

This is similar to having it invoke a script but without needing a separate file.