# Using a big regex in awk

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I have a regex that works fine in `awk`, but first I need to store the regex in a shell variable

`valLat="^[-+]?(([0-9]+[d])?([0-9]+['])?([0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+[\"])?|[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+)[NnSs]?$"`

then pass the shell variable to an `awk` variable like this

`echo 39d41\'17.766\"N | awk -v valLat=$valLat '{ if ($1 ~ valLat) print $1; else print "erro" }'
39d41'17.766"N`

This works, but I want do this without using a shell variable. I've tried to use the escape "\" preceding the special characters without success.

Comment: What do you mean without the variable? You mean a) `awk -v valLat="^[-+]?..."`, or b) `awk '{ if ($1 ~ /^[-+]?...`?

Comment: One way or another... I don't want to use a bash variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the script in a file and use awk -f on it or use ANSI escape sequences or define a variable for the single quote, e.g. using `\x27` for the single quote:

```
$ echo 39d41\'17.766\"N | awk '$1 ~ /^[-+]?(([0-9]+[d])?([0-9]+[\x27])?([0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+["])?|[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+)[NnSs]?$/'
39d41'17.766"N
```

Answer (score 0):

[There is no way to escape single-quotes inside of single-quoted strings in bash.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1250079/1979174)
So you should use double-quotes for awk script.

```
echo 39d41\'17.766\"N | awk "{ if (\$1 ~ /^[-+]?(([0-9]+[d])?([0-9]+[\'])?([0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+[\"])?|[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+)[NnSs]?$/ ) print \$1; else print \"error\" }"
```

Comment: No, you should never use double quotes as it makes the script much too complicated. Put the script in a file an use `awk -f` on it or use ANSI escape sequences or define a variable for he single quote.

Comment: @EdMorton Is my script much complicated than yours? I don't think so. On other point of view create another file for awk one-liner is kind of complication. In case of big pieces of awk code you right.

Comment: It's not that THAT SCRIPT is much more complicated, it's that THAT APPROACH needlessly produces much more complicated scripts as you then need to remember escape double quotes, $ signs, backslashes, etc. It's just never the right way to solve this problem when there's much simpler, more robust ways to do it.

Comment: In your script, for example: I really don't know if the `$` at the end of your RE needs to be escaped or not but the `'` in the middle of the RE should not be escaped. Its probably harmless but I don't know for sure - it MAY mean `\ or '` instead of just `'`. You simply don't have to care about this kind of "special case" stuff if you just don't use double quotes as the delimiter.

Comment: Thank you both, today I've learned a very basic important thing...
@EdMorton your solutions turned to be the more interesting.

Answer (score 0):

no need to "store into file" : just use octals

shell variable

```
valLat='^[-+]?(([0-9]+[d])?([0-9]+\47)?([0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+\42)?|[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+)[NnSs]?$'
```

matching against input

```
echo 39d41\'17.766\"N |
```

> ```
> mawk -F"$valLat" NF==2
> ```