# SQL insert bash

Tags: mysql, sql, bash, insert

I am new to MySQL and I would like to insert into table something from bash script. Found some ways from google and it works for simple commands select * from foo but it wont work for my insert.

```
#!/bin/bash

qry="INSERT INTO  `video`.`asdf` (`DB_ID` , `LNX_ID` , `STIME` , `ETIME` , `TEXT` ) VALUES ( NULL , '5', '00:00:41.900', '00:00:49.600', 'Na leteckej v23423.');"

mysql --host=localhost --database 'video' --user=user --password=password << eof
$qry
eof
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing an error message, immediate asssumption is that bash is attempting to execute commands inside backticks, since you have double-quoted the string assigned to `qry`, and finding no command `video`, for example, it prints an error.

```
$ echo "This will show the date if I do `date` in backticks"
> This will show the date if I do Sat Jun 29 22:09:59 CDT 2013 in backticks
```

Escape the backticks with backslashes inside the double-quoted string to prevent bash from attempting to evaluate them.

```
qry="INSERT INTO  \`video\`.\`asdf\` (\`DB_ID\` , \`LNX_ID\` , \`STIME\` , \`ETIME\` , \`TEXT\` ) VALUES (    NULL , '5', '00:00:41.900', '00:00:49.600', 'Na leteckej v23423.');"
```

None of your column and table names [are reserved keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), however, and therefore don't need to be quoted at all.

```
qry="INSERT INTO  video.asdf (DB_ID , LNX_ID , STIME , ETIME , TEXT) VALUES (NULL , '5', '00:00:41.900', '00:00:49.600', 'Na leteckej v23423.');"
```

The other alternative is to use single quotes on the outer string, but that will necessitate very clumsy quoting to maintain single quotes on your inserted column values, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/bash-escaping-single-quotes-inside-of-single-quoted-strings)

Comment: Thank you backshlash help me with this issue. Thank you...