# Unexpected EOF in .bashrc alias

Tags: echo, bash, xclip

I am getting an unexpected end of file error after including this line in my .bashrc

```
alias domsrv01='echo -e ?HT_R8\'% | xclip ; ssh 10.50.0.35'
```

The desired exit from echo to xclip is:

> ?HT_R8'%

As you may guess, it's a password and I can't change it so:

How can I escape the single quote character from inside the password to fix the EOF error?

Also, I'm not sure if the single quote is the only issue here, can "?" and "%" be interpreted in funny ways too?

Comment: What about this? `alias domsrv01="echo -e \"?HT_R8\'%\" | xclip ; ssh 10.50.0.35"`

Comment: So you just posted your *password*?

Comment: @devnull of course it's not the exact password, but it still contains the same special characters from the original.

Comment: @fedorqui it doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly escape singe quotes within single quotes in bash. However, since bash concatenates adjacent strings, you can use this construct instead `'text'"'"'moretest'`. You actually end the single quoted string with a single quote, and immediately add a double quoted single quote, followed by the remaining of the string (in single quotes). In your specific example, the command would look like this:

```
alias domsrv01='echo -e ?HT_R8\'"'"'% | xclip ; ssh 10.50.0.35'
```

More discussion on the topic can be fount here: [How to escape single-quotes within single-quoted strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/bash-escaping-single-quotes-inside-of-single-quoted-strings)

Edited: Added the missing backlash noticed by @GordonDavisson

Comment: or `'text'\''moretest'` (same as `alias` command, with no parameter outputs.)

Comment: For some reason this still fails. Try this: alias test1='echo -e ?HT_R8'"'"'% | xclip | xclip -o'. It should return the echo output to xclip but it doesn't.

Comment: @sergei You are right, it doesn't... a workaround might be to use a function like `test2() { echo -e '?HT_R8'"'"'%' | xclip | xclip -o; }` . (unalias the existing alias first if you use the same name)

Comment: It's missing the baskslash in the alias itself, so when you use the alias it results in an unterminated single-quoted string. Try: `alias domsrv01='echo -e ?HT_R8\'"'"'% | xclip ; ssh 10.50.0.35'`

Answer (score 1):

Aliases are intended for short text replacements, not full blown shell commands. Use a function:

```
domsrv01 () {
    echo -e ?HT_R8\'% | xclip ; ssh 10.50.0.35
}
```

Comment: This aliases file started as a lazy replacement for a connection manager for more than 100 servers. I may need to move to functions sometime in the future, so I'll keep that in mind.