# Single quote escaping in Bash within a single quoted string

Tags: bash, shell

**The problem**

I'm trying to create a kickstart file automatically, and the tool I'm using to parse it requires the kickstart to be supplied as a string in single quotes.

Most of it is fine, except the postinstall script which uses AWK, hence single quotes within single quotes.

I've looked at some of the other posts and tried escaping the strings, to no avail.

I've clearly mis-understood some fundamental principal of escaping.

**The code**

```
DATA='
GATEWAY=$(localcli network ip route ipv4 list | grep default | awk \'{print $3}\')
'
echo ${DATA}
```

**The desired output**

This is the literal output string I'd like to see.

```
GATEWAY=$(localcli network ip route ipv4 list | grep default | awk '{print $3}')
```

Comment: Related: *[How to escape single quotes within single quoted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you can't escape characters within the single-quoted string, you have to do it outside of it:

```
~$ echo 'abc'\''cde'
abc'cde
```

Alternatively, use a double-quoted string (requires escaping `$`)

```
DATA="
GATEWAY=\$(localcli network ip route ipv4 list | grep default | awk '{print \$3}')
"
```

Comment: The double quoted string looks like the best solution for me.

Thanks very much!

Comment: The simplest way I know of is to use ```printf``` to convert any string to a bash-escaped string: ```printf "%q" "$str"```

Answer (score 2):

There is a little-known third type of quotes—`$'...'`—available to `bash` in which you can escape single quotes:

```
DATE=$'GATEWAY=$(...| awk \'/default/ {print $3}\')'
```

(This also demonstrates why piping `grep` into `awk` is often unnecessary.)

Comment: For [Bash 2.04 and later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings/16605140#16605140)?

Answer (score 0):

If you **must** use single quotes in your `DATA` variable definition, replacing `awk` with `cut` could be a workaround.

e.g.:

```
$ echo "first second third" > ex.txt
$ awk '{print $3}' ex.txt
third
$ cut -d" " -f3 ex.txt
third
```