# Executing below system command through ruby

Tags: ruby, macos, shell, rspec

I am executing a system command with ruby. The code  is like this

```
commandtoexecute=“pararellrspec --type rspec -n 1 --test-options '--test "cases's owner"' testing/multi/getcreate.rb “

system(commandtoexecute)
```

On executing the above line it gives error

```
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

But when I execute by replacing cases's with casess above it works. Does any one has any idea how to prevent this error above without replacing "cases's" with "casess"

Comment: Have you tried escaping it `'..."cases\'s owner"...'?

Comment: can  not do that . The string "--test "cases's owner""  is stored in a variable which is subsituted while making the command. So there is no way to try cases\'s

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your double-quotes:

```
"pararellrspec --type rspec -n 1 --test-options '--test \"cases's owner\"' testing/multi/getcreate.rb"
```

Edit: possibly that line single quote as well, come to think of it:

```
"pararellrspec --type rspec -n 1 --test-options '--test \"cases\'s owner\"' testing/multi/getcreate.rb"
```

Or perhaps remove the single quotes instead of that if works as expected:

```
"pararellrspec --type rspec -n 1 --test-options --test \"cases's owner\" testing/multi/getcreate.rb"
```

Alternatively (and better yet), use the array flavor of `system` when appropriate, so as to have Ruby take care of quoting arguments for you:

```
system("echo *")
system("echo", "*")
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-system

Answer (score 0):

```
commandtoexecute="pararellrspec --type rspec -n 1 --test-options '--test "cases's owner"' testing/multi/getcreate.rb"
system(commandtoexecute)
```

as you can see you have an escaping issue with " and ' within your command string. to circumvent this issue, you can use

```
%x(ruby --copyright)
> "ruby - Copyright (C) 1993-2013 Yukihiro Matsumoto\n"
```

to execute the shell command within ruby. This shorthand method takes care of any necessary escaping. So your original code comes down to:

```
%x(pararellrspec --type rspec -n 1 --test-options '--test "cases's owner"' testing/multi/getcreate.rb)
```

as you can see, because you dont need `"` to create a string that holds your command (as you did above for `commandtoexecute`) the escaping issue is gone.

Comment: I didn't get it ... should the command be like  system(%x(commandtoexecute))

Comment: no, something like: `%x(pararellrspec --type rspec -n 1 --test-options --test "cases's owner" testing/multi/getcreate.rb)`

this will execute the command as a system command, and should take care of correct escaping

Comment: sry unable to understand this. Tried '%x(commandtoexecute)' and 'system(%x(commandtoexecute))'

Answer (score 0):

Not sure please try like this:-

```
1.9.3p448 :025 > commandtoexecute="pararellrspec --type rspec -n 1 --test-options '--test 'cases\'s owner' testing/multi/getcreate.rb"

  => "pararellrspec --type rspec -n 1 --test-options '--test 'cases's owner' testing/multi/getcreate.rb"

1.9.3p448 :026 > system(commandtoexecute)
```

this will work please try it.

Please [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/escaping-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings) more details.