# How to echo a string with any content in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, scripting

I'm having an extremely hard time figuring out how to echo this:

```
![alt text](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/raw/master/src/common/images/icon48.png "Logo Title Text 1")
```

I keep getting this error:

```
bash: ![alt: event not found
```

Using double quotes around it does not work. The using single quotes around it does work, however, I also need to echo strings that have single quotes within them. I wouldn't be able to wrap the string with single quotes then.

Is there a way to echo a string of ANY content?

Thanks.

EDIT: Here is some context. I am making a Markdown renderer that grabs the content of a code editor, then appends every line of the code individually into a text file. I am doing this by doing this:

```
echo TheLineOfMarkdown > textfile.txt
```

Comment: You can go with single-quotes and try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/escaping-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings

Comment: where exactly does this string come from? please provide more context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike in many programing languages, `'...'` and `"..."` in Bash do not represent "strings" *per se*; they quote/escape whatever they contain, but they do not create boundaries that separate arguments. So, for example, these two commands are equivalent:

```
echo foobar
echo "fo"ob'ar'
```

So if you need to quote some of an argument with single-quotes, and a different part of the argument has to contain single-quotes — no problem.

For example:

```
echo '![alt text](https://... "What'"'"'s up, Doc?")'
```

Another option is to use `\`, which is similar to `'...'` except that it only quotes a single character. It can even be used inside double-quotes:

```
echo "\![alt text](https://... \"What's up, Doc?\")"
```

For more information, see [§3.1.2 "Quoting" in the *Bash Reference Manual*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Quoting).

Comment: Ah, but the thing is, I don't know what I'll need to echo beforehand. I won't be able to add anything to the inside of the string, only something around the string. I've added an edit that provides some context on what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Regnarg: Please, *please* tell me that you are not injecting untrusted text into dynamically-generated Bash scripts for the sake of pasting it into a file. :-/ There must be a better, safer way. (For starters -- instead of injecting the text into a Bash script, why not just inject it directly into the intended file?)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if that's what I'm doing, but it kind of sounds like it. I thought it would be a simple task (it may still be), but I haven't been able to find an simple solution to it. I'm literally just trying to replace a file's content with a string that contains new line characters, but echo $string > file.txt did not work well. Any idea how I would do that via commandline?

Comment: @Regnarg: Wait, are you saying that this isn't in a shell script or anything, but rather, you're manually typing this at the command line? And the problem with complex quoting isn't that you *can't* properly quote a given string, but rather, that you're just looking for a way that doesn't involve as much manual effort? If so, then -- let me know, I can update my answer to show you an easier way. :-)

Comment: Re: "a string that contains new line characters, but echo $string > file.txt did not work well": Right. You need `echo "$string" > file.txt` instead, to prevent word-splitting and filename expansion on the contents of `$string`.

Comment: Arg, I'm getting so many different answers about what I'm supposed to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23599061/how-to-replace-a-files-content-with-a-string-containing-new-line-characters

Comment: @Regnarg: Seems like lots of people have told you to use `echo "$string"` instead of `echo $string`, so the answers are not so different.

Comment: @Regnarg: You're getting different answers because people are having trouble figuring out exactly what you're trying to do. ruakh's answer is correct *if the string is being entered as part of the command itself*. Your other question refers to a string *read from a file into a variable, then used* (and also needing `\n` translated to newline). If the string is given directly in the command line, you have to adapt your quoting to what characters it contains; if it's in a variable, double-quotes are (almost) always the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>!</kbd> is annoying. My advice: Use <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>!</kbd>.

<kbd>!</kbd> invokes history completion, which is also performed inside double-quotes. So you need to single-quote the exclamation mark, but as you say that conflicts with the need to not single-quote other single-quotes.

Remember that you can mix quotes:

```
$ echo '!'"'"'"'
!'"
```

(That's just one argument.) But in this case, the backslash is easier to type and quite possibly more readable.

Comment: Ah, but the thing is, I don't know what I'll need to echo beforehand. I've added an edit that provides some context on what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: @Regnarg: I don't get it. Are you programmatically generating the `echo foo >> textfile` lines? (Append is `>>`, `>` is overwrite).