# How to replace a file's content with a string containing new line characters?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

When I read "line1\nline2\nline3" into a string, like this:

```
read string

line1\nline2\nline3
```

Then echo the string and direct the output to a file:

```
echo $string > text.txt
```

The txt file now contains:

```
line1nline2nline3
```

How could I make it so that the file contains:

```
line1
line2
line2
```

?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `\n` does not mean line feed. It's just unnecessarily escaping the value of `n`.

To do what you want, you should.

1. Read a string in a way that preserves backslashes
2. Expand any escape sequences and write the string out

You can do 1. with `read -r` and 2. with `echo -e`:

```
read -r string
echo -e "$string"
```

Comment: +1 for the correct answer. For OP, please read [BashFAQ/001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Just put `$string` in double-quotes:

```
echo "$string" > text.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add double-quotes.

Example:

```
$ example=line1\nline2
$ echo $example
line1nline2
```

With double-quotes:

```
$ example="line1\nline2"
$ echo $example
line1
line2
```

Saving:

```
$ echo $example >> example.txt
$ cat example.txt
line1
line2
```