# how to override a single inverted comma in awk command

Tags: shell, unix

How to override a single inverted comma in `awk` command.

```
cat a.txt |awk '{print "Students name is '"$1"'"}'
```

I want output as below:

```
Students name is 'Rajeev'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
echo ff | awk $'{print "Students name is \'" $1 "\'" }'
```

Words of the form $'string' are treated specially. The word expands to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard. Backslash escape sequences, if present, are decoded as follows:

```
  \\     backslash
  \'     single quote
  \"     double quote
  \n     new line
  ...
```

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16605140/2413778)

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
awk -v q="'" '{print "Students name is " q $1 q}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `'"'"'` for each single quote that you want in the output.

The first quote ends the single quoted string. Then we start a double quoted string which simply expands to a single quote. Then we enter a new single quoted string for the rest of the command.

Since there are no spaces between the strings, bash will string them together. i.e. `"a"'b'` is the same as `"ab"` or `'ab'`

Answer (score 1):

To avoid escaping an other tricks you can use it's octal representation,as:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print "\047"}'
'
```

So:

```
$ awk '{print "Students name is \047"$1"\047"}' a.txt
```