# How to escape single quote in sed?

Tags: sed, escaping, quote

How to escape a single quote in a sed expression that is already surrounded by quotes?

For example:

```bash
sed 's/ones/one's/' <<< 'ones thing'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escaping single-quotes within single-quoted strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/escaping-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings)

Comment: The short answer is "[you can't do that](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Single-Quotes)" -- the workarounds presented all work well.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Quote `sed` codes with double quotes:

```
$ sed "s/ones/one's/"<<<"ones thing"   
one's thing
```

I don't like escaping codes with hundreds of backslashes – hurts my eyes. Usually I do in this way:

```
$ sed 's/ones/one\x27s/'<<<"ones thing"
one's thing
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with `sed -i`, any particular reason?

Comment: It should be noted that surrounding  sed commands with double quotes allows those commands to be interpolated by the shell and may lead to unforeseen problems.

Comment: this led to the answer I was looking for which ended up being: `echo "one's thing" | sed 's/\x27/\\'"'"'/g'` >> `$ one\'s thing`

Comment: Whether or not this works with `sed -i` is a red herring. Not all `sed` dialects accept hex codes like `\x27`, irrespective of whether you pass in the `-i` flag.

Comment: @matttrach Simplier: `echo "one's thing" | sed 's/\x27/\\&/g'`

Answer (score 61):

One trick is to use shell string concatenation of adjacent strings and escape the embedded quote using shell escaping:

`sed 's/ones/two'\''s/' <<< 'ones thing'`

```
two's thing
```

There are 3 strings in the sed expression, which the shell then stitches together:

`sed 's/ones/two'`

`\'`

`'s/'`

Comment: perhaps an easier variant: sed 's/ones/two''s/' <<< 'ones thing'

Comment: @gregory: `sed 's/ones/two''s/' <<< 'ones thing'` No, that outputs `twos thing`. It's missing the `'` in the output. You have to do it the way described in this answer.

Comment: @wisbucky  With the version of sed I'm using (FreeBSD/macOS) on zsh, it definitely outputs "two's thing."

Comment: great help man by letting me know, shell then stitches together.

Answer (score 15):

## Escaping single quote in [sed](/questions/tagged/sed): 3 different ways:

From fragile to solid...

**Note**: This answer is based on **[GNU `sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)**!!

### 1. Using double-quotes to enclose *sed script*:

Simpliest way:

```bash
sed "s/ones/one's/" <<< 'ones thing'
```

But using double-quote lead to shell variables expansion and backslashes to be considered as shell escape **before** running `sed`.

#### 1.1. Specific case without space and special chars

In this specific case, you could avoid enclosing at shell level (command line):

```
sed s/ones/one\'s/ <<<'ones thing'
```

will work until whole sedscript don't contain spaces, semicolons, special characters and so on... (fragile!)

### 2. Using *octal* or *hexadecimal* representation:

This way is simple and efficient, if not as readable as next one.

```bash
sed 's/ones/one\o047s/' <<< 'ones thing'

sed 's/ones/one\x27s/' <<< 'ones thing'
```

And as following character (`s`) is not a digit, you coul write octal with only 2 digits:

```bash
sed 's/ones/one\o47s/' <<< 'ones thing'
```

### 3. Creating a dedicated *sed script*

```
cat <<eosedscript >sampleSedWithQuotes.sed
#!$(which sed) -f

s/ones/one's/;
eosedscript
chmod +x sampleSedWithQuotes.sed
```

From there, you could run:

```
./sampleSedWithQuotes.sed <<<'ones thing'
one's thing
```

This is the strongest and simpliest solution as your script is **the most** readable:
`$ cat sampleSedWithQuotes.sed`

```
#!/bin/sed -f

s/ones/one's/;
```

#### 3.1 You coud use `-i` sed flag:

As this *script* use `sed` in shebang, you could use `sed` flags on command line. For editing `file.txt` ***in place***, with the `-i` flag:

```
echo >file.txt 'ones thing'
./sampleSedWithQuotes.sed -i file.txt
cat file.txt
one's thing
```

#### 3.2 Mixing quotes AND double quotes

Using *dedicated script* may simplify mixing quotes and double quotes in same script.

Adding a new operation in our script to enclose the word *thing* in double quotes:

```bash
echo >>sampleSedWithQuotes.sed 's/\bthing\b/"&"/;'
```

> ( now our script look like:
>
> ```
>  #!/bin/sed -f
>  
>  s/ones/one's/;
>  s/\bthing\b/"&"/;
> ```
>
> )

then

```
./sampleSedWithQuotes.sed <<<'ones thing'
one's "thing"
```

Comment: it's weird i've tried all the solutions and they all failed except for the one with \o047

Comment: @SLP Did you use ***GNU `sed`***?

Answer (score 8):

The best way is to use `$'some string with \' quotes \''`

eg:

```
sed $'s/ones/two\'s/' <<< 'ones thing'
```

Comment: The C-style `$'string'` is Bash-specific, so it's not portable to POSIX shell.

Comment: It's not `bash` specific.  It's also available in `ksh` and `zsh`, but yes, it's an extension to POSIX, which is fine if you aren't writing a portable script.  The only downside is that you have to escape any other backslashes you use as well.

Comment: *The best way* clearly depend on your use case!
There is not only one best way! Have a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66703200/1765658)

Answer (score 8):

Just use double quotes on the outside of the sed command.

```
$ sed "s/ones/one's/" <<< 'ones thing'
one's thing
```

It works with files too.

```
$ echo 'ones thing' > testfile
$ sed -i "s/ones/one's/" testfile
$ cat testfile
one's thing
```

If you have single *and* double quotes inside the string, that's ok too. Just escape the double quotes.

For example, this file contains a string with both single and double quotes. I'll use sed to add a single quote and remove some double quotes.

```
$ cat testfile
"it's more than ones thing"
$ sed -i "s/\"it's more than ones thing\"/it's more than one's thing/" testfile 
$ cat testfile 
it's more than one's thing
```

Comment: Thanks! I love regex, love sed and now I love you <3

Comment: This basically duplicates the accepted answer from 2014.

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of absurd but I couldn't get `\'` in `sed 's/ones/one\'s/'` to work. I was looking this up to make a shell script that will automatically add `import 'hammerjs';` to my `src/main.ts` file with Angular.

What I did get to work is this:

```
apost=\'
sed -i '' '/environments/a\
import '$apost'hammerjs'$apost';' src/main.ts
```

So for the example above, it would be:

```
apost=\'
sed 's/ones/one'$apost's/'
```

I have no idea why `\'` wouldn't work by itself, but there it is.

Comment: It's because ["A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash."](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Single-Quotes) The [answer above by Thomas Bratt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509214/how-to-escape-single-quote-in-sed/24509305#24509305) explains the proper workaround.

Comment: Yes or replace `$apost` by `\'`:  `sed 's/ones/one'\''s/'` will work too.

Answer (score 0):

Some escapes on AppleMacOSX terminals fail so:

```bash
sed 's|ones|one'$(echo -e "\x27")'s|1'  <<<'ones thing'
```

Comment: `echo -e` isn't properly portable either, and running a subprocess just to get it to print a literal single quote is silly. The simple expression `sed 's|ones|one'\''s|'` would work just as well. That's `s|ones|one` in single quotes, followed by a literal escaped single quote `\'` followed by `|s` in single quotes. (The trailing `1` is completely redundant.)

Answer (score -2):

use an alternative string seperator like ":" to avoid confusion with different slashes

```bash
sed "s:ones:one's:" <<< 'ones thing'
```

or if you wish to highligh the single quote

```bash
sed "s:ones:one\'s:" <<< 'ones thing'
```

both return

```
one's thing
```

Comment: That's not the issue here at all; the OP's code has no slashes.  This is a good answer to a completely different question which has however been answered hundreds of times before on this site.