# find and replace in linux within entire directory and escaping special characters

Tags: linux, unix, terminal

I am trying to find every file that has

```
$status=='access'||!Yii::app()->user->isGuest
```

and replace it with

```
$status=='access'
```

Is there an easy way to accomplish this in linux. I tried using the following example (which replaces windows with linux), but couldn't get it to work. It doesn't throw any errors.

```
grep -rl 'windows' ./ | xargs sed -i 's/windows/linux/g'

grep -rl "\$status=='access'||\!Yii::app()->user->isGuest
" ./ | xargs sed -i 's/\$status=='access'||\!Yii::app()->user->isGuest
/$status=='access'/g'
```

Comment: There are double-quotes inside the sed that sed is trying to match, but not in the file(s).

Comment: Originally, I didn't have double quotes. I received an error. Is it because sed can't escape the single quotes the way I have written it? I have edited my post to show what I tried.

Comment: @SamKingston: You need to escape the single quotes, since the shell doesn't allow single quotes between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash (or at least, bash doesn't). try `"s/\\\$status=='access'||\!Yii::app()->user->isGuest/\$status=='access'/g"`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509214/how-to-escape-single-quote-in-sed