# How to escape characters in sed

Tags: sed

I'm trying to remove some text from multiple files using sed. This is the text I'm trying to delete:

```
\once override TupletBracket #'stencil = ##f
```

I've tried this line in sed but I can't get it to work:

```
sed -i '' -e 's/\\once \\override TupletBracket #'stencil = ##f//g' *ily
```

I've tried escaping the `#` symbols, the `'` and the `=` but still no joy. Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape single quote in sed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509214/how-to-escape-single-quote-in-sed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't use `'` directly inside sed command that is quoted using `'`. Use a double quotes instead and to match `\` you'll need to use `\\\` to have `\\` i.e `\`.

```
$ sed "s/\\\once override TupletBracket #'stencil = ##f//g"
\once override TupletBracket #'stencil = ##f

hello \once override TupletBracket #'stencil = ##f xyz
hello  xyz
$
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to use single quotes here rather than double quotes to avoid the extra `\`s and other possible expansions (e.g. variables).  Where you want a literal single quote, you close the quotation, add `\'`, and then start a new quotation for the remainder.

```
$ cat in
before \once override TupletBracket #'stencil = ##f after
$ sed 's/\\once override TupletBracket #'\''stencil = ##f//g' in
before  after
```

Comment: There are separate reasons for why the `\\` and `'` need to be quoted. In the first case `\\` is used to quote characters in the LHS of the substitute command and therefore must also be quoted. The `'` is part of the shell which is quoting the sed command and must be quoted first in the shell and concatenated to the command.

Answer (score 0):

`#` and `=` are not RE metacharacters nor do they have any other special meaning to sed within a regexp (`=` does outside of a regexp) unless the regexp is delimited with one of them so there's no reason to escape them in your script. `'` only has significance if the whole script is delimited with `'`s since in shell no script that's delimited by a given character can include that character. So here's your choices:

```
$ echo "seab'cd" | sed 's/b'\''c/foo/'
seafood

$ echo "seab'cd" | sed "s/b'c/foo/"
seafood
```

Note that if you use the second (double quotes) version then you're allowing shell variables to expand inside the script and would require double-backslashes to escape chars.

I expected using the octal representation of a `'` (i.e. `\047`) would work too like it does in awk:

```
$ echo "seab'cd" | awk '{sub(/b\047c/,"foo")}1'
seafood
```

but it didn't:

```
$ echo "seab'cd" | sed 's/b\047c/foo/'
seab'cd
```

and I suspect that's because sed is treating `\0` as a backreference. It does work with the hex representation:

```
$ echo "seab'cd" | sed 's/b\x27c/foo/'
seafood
```

but that's dangerous and should be avoided (see http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote).