# Sed command to replace a string with special character

Tags: bash, sed

So I have a this below line in a file which has special characters & I want to replace it with another line.

Line present in file -

```
'generic_raid': {'keys': 5 * (1000**3)
```

Line with which I want to replace the above line-

```
'generic_raid': {'keys': 2
```

I am using the below sed command but it is not working, can anyone please help

```
sudo sed -r -i "s/'generic_raid': \{'keys': 5 * (1000**3)/'generic_raid': \{'keys': 2/g" abc.py
```

Comment: escape curly braces, *, (, )

Comment: Thanks a lot Avinash, it worked. I used the below command -     sudo sed -r -i "s/'generic_raid': \{'keys': 5 \* \(1000\*\*3\)/'generic_raid': \{'keys': 2/g" abc.py

Comment: And in a pinch, if you're not sure whether you need to escape something, you can put a character into square brackets. `[*]` matches `*`, `[{]` matches `{`, etc.

Comment: To expand on Avinash's comment, [this regexr](http://regexr.com/3eaki) is your search pattern - red underlines are errors.

Comment: Thanks ghoti & cxw for the suggestions, appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

can simplify by avoiding use of extended regex, only `*` needs to be escaped in this case

```
$ cat ip.txt 
'generic_raid': {'keys': 5 * (1000**3)
$ sed "s/'generic_raid': {'keys': 5 \* (1000\*\*3)/'generic_raid': {'keys': 2/g" ip.txt 
'generic_raid': {'keys': 2
```

not required in this case, but if `"` is undesirable and `'` features in pattern, ascii code `\x27` can be used

```
$ sed 's/\x27generic_raid\x27: {\x27keys\x27: 5 \* (1000\*\*3)/\x27generic_raid\x27: {\x27keys\x27: 2/g' ip.txt 
'generic_raid': {'keys': 2
```

Also, a `perl` solution which has a `\Q` feature helpful in these cases:

```
$ perl -pe "s/\Q'generic_raid': {'keys': 5 * (1000**3)/'generic_raid': {'keys': 2/" ip.txt 
'generic_raid': {'keys': 2
```

From [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html)

> Returns the value of EXPR with all the ASCII non-"word" characters
>   backslashed. (That is, all ASCII characters not matching
>   /[A-Za-z_0-9]/ will be preceded by a backslash in the returned string,
>   regardless of any locale settings.)

Comment: Always use octal `\047`, never hex `\x27` to represent a single quote. See http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote. YMMV with either in sed of course.

Comment: @EdMorton does it affect `sed`? didn't affect for me on `GNU sed 4.2.2`

Comment: Y'know I'm not sure. I assumed so but I always use `'\''` with sed so idk.

Comment: didn't see your edit before I left the comment, searched around a bit and see that `\x27` is commonly used, for ex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509214/how-to-escape-single-quote-in-sed ... thanks for warning though, will remember for `awk` or elsewhere if something is fishy :)

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately on this site and others you'll find lots of examples endorsing the use of everything you should never actually do since they often produce the expected output for a given sample input and only fail later given different input. In this case, I'd personally avoid `\x27` anyway and use `'\''` if `\047` doesn't work for you since `\x27`s been proven to be problematic in other text processing tools/situations but YMMV I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Since sed doesn't have any string operations, it takes a lot of work to force a sed expression to behave as if it were working with strings (see [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed)) so just don't. Instead use awk since it supports string operations:

```
awk -v old="'generic_raid': {'keys': 5 * (1000**3)" \
    -v new="'generic_raid': {'keys': 2" \
       's=index($0,old){$0=substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+length(old))} 1' file
'generic_raid': {'keys': 2
```