# Sed: How to insert a pattern which includes single ticks?

Tags: sed

I'm trying to use sed to replace a specific line within a configuration file:

The pattern for the line I want to replace is:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS.*
```

The text I want to insert is:

```
'$PublicIP' (Including the single ticks)
```

But when I run the command:

```
sed 's/ALLOWED_HOSTS.*/ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['$PublicIP']/g' /root/project/django/mysite/mysite/settings.py
```

The line is changed to:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [1.1.1.1]
```

instead of:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['1.1.1.1']
```

How shall I edit the command to include the single ticks as well?

Comment: use `\x27` to represent single quotes...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape single quote in sed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509214/how-to-escape-single-quote-in-sed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to escape the single ticks , or better you can reassign the variable including the simple ticks:

```
PublicIP="'$PublicIP'".
```

By the way even this sed without redifining var, works ok in my case:

```
$ a="3.3.3.3"
$ echo "ALLOWED_HOSTS = [2.2.2.2]" |sed 's/2.2.2.2/'"'$a'"'/g'
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['3.3.3.3']
```

Even this works ok:

```
$ echo "ALLOWED_HOSTS = [2.2.2.2]" |sed "s/2.2.2.2/'$a'/g"
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['3.3.3.3']
```

Comment: @Itai Ganot Updated.