# how to use single quotes in replacement string using sed in linux?

Tags: linux, sed

I want to replace the below string

`su - oracle -c "$agent_home/bin/emctl control agent runCollection ex01cel01:oracle_exadata oracle_exadata_configuration"`

to replace with

`su - oracle -c "'$agent_home'/bin/emctl control agent runCollection ex01cel01 :oracle_exadata oracle_exadata_configuration"`

note:extra single quotes covering the $agent_home

Please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape single quote in sed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509214/how-to-escape-single-quote-in-sed)

Comment: where is `sed(1)` called on this question?  don't misuse the tags, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following sed command should do it

```
sed "s|\$agent_home|'\$agent_home'|"
```

Comment: or `sed 's/$agent_home/\x27&\x27/'` to avoid worrying about escaping shell interpretations in double quotes