# linux sed substitusion with regex fails

Tags: regex, sed

So I have the following regex that works, but not with `sed`

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hkHKxr/1)

```
^(\S*HTTPS*_SERVER\S*)(\s*'https*:\/\/)(\S*)('\);)$
```

and the text in my `file.txt`:

```
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://localhost:31270');
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://localhost:31270');
```

then when I try to do:

```
sed -i.bak -r 's/^\(\S*HTTPS*_SERVER\S*\)\(\s*\'https*:\/\/\)\(\S*\)\(\'\);\)$/\1\2test.com\4/' file.txt
```

it doesn't do anything.

Any ideas what it is wrong here? Is it because of the escaping char?

Comment: If you are using POSIX ERE, `\(` must be turned into `(` (and `\)` into `)`). Well, you might as well remove `-r` option.

Comment: I tried with -r and without, the same with escaping `(` and `)` or not escaping and still doesn't work

Comment: Yes, I see, there is a `'` inside the pattern. You should  use double quotes around `s/.../.../` command.

Comment: What version of sed are you using? The GNU version may support `\S` and `\s`, but I suspect no other varieties will. If you want to use posix classes, best to spell them out for clarity and portability.

Comment: yes I use a GNU version (4.4), thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using POSIX ERE syntax (`-r` option) a capturing group is defined with a pair of *unescaped* `(` and `)`. Besides, since you have a `'` inside the pattern, you need to use doulbe quotes around the `s/.../.../` command.

Use

```
sed -i.bak -r "s/^(\S*HTTPS*_SERVER\S*)(\s*'https*:\/\/)(\S*)('\);)$/\1\2test.com\4/" file.txt
```

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/Z23pCs).

Note that you may use delimiters other than `/` to avoid escaping `/` symbols, in the pattern (say, you may use `"s,<pattern>,<replacement>,"`, as there are no commas in the pattern itself). Besdies, as per this thread, if you really need to use a single quoted regex definition, you may replace a literal `'` in the pattern with a `\x27` entity.

Also, *if you need not insert any text in between Group 1 and Group 2*, you may merge the two group patterns into one, and - as you are removing Group 3, you do not even need to capture it.

So, an alternative could look like

```
sed -r 's,^(\S*HTTPS*_SERVER\S*\s*\x27https*://)\S*(\x27\);)$,\1test.com\2,' file.txt
```

See [another online demo](https://ideone.com/Ri7X70).

Comment: that is true, I found another work around https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509214/how-to-escape-single-quote-in-sed which it uses `\x27` for the single quotes. But your explanation is a valid answer

Comment: @Edwin Yes, the single quotes can be freely used if you define the regex within double quotes.

Comment: just to be an complete answer, maybe edit and add either the link to the single quote alternative or just add the solution to your answer.

Comment: ah, you mean with `\x27`

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the number of capturing groups:

```
sed -E -i.bak "s/^(define\('HTTPS?_SERVER', 'https?:\/\/)[^']*('\);)/\1test.com\2/" file.txt
```

Comment: that's an improvement to my regex, but not the answer to the question, tho I will up vote this! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Edwin Wiktor Stribiżew's answer explains why your regex doesn't work with sed. My answer is just an alternative.