# How can I escape a single quote in ag (without using double quotes)

Tags: ag

How can I escape a single quote in ag when searching for an expression like this one?

```
ag ''react-redux''
```

I'm aware that `"'react-redux'"` is one solution in this scenario, but I'd like a solution that lets me use single quotes. That way I don't have to worry about the complex escape sequences required by `$`, `%`, etc. when using double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use \x27 to represent single quotes. (\x27 is just the ascii code for single quotes)
thus, you can use:

```
ag '\x27react-redux\x27'
```

ref: [How to escape single quote in sed? --stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24509931/4748971)

Answer (score 1):

While \x27 works, it's obscure. The standard approach is triple single quotes. So, if you want to escape single quotes around `'react-redux'` you'd surround each single quote with a pair of single quotes: `'''react-redux'''`. 
For example:

```
$ag '''DD-MON-YYYY''' users.sql
19:       TO_CHAR(lock_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY') AS lock_date,
20:       TO_CHAR(expiry_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY') AS expiry_date,
23:       TO_CHAR(created, 'DD-MON-YYYY') AS created,
```

So, a trivial example to only match quoted items:

```
$touch test.txt
$echo value >> test.txt
$echo '''value''' >> test.txt
$echo value >> test.txt
$ < test.txt 
value
'value'
value
$ ag '''value''' test.txt
2:'value'
```

Comment: When I try this I get all occurrences of `react-redux`, quotes or no quotes.

Comment: Then something in your shell is interfering, this should ONLY match quoted items. I'll provide an example in the main answer.

Comment: Try ag \'react-redux\'

Comment: Works, but then I can't use regex syntax.

Comment: @adc17, Which of my suggestions works? And why can't you use regex syntax -- where/how are you using it?

Comment: e.g. I can't use  `ag \'react-red.*\'`

Comment: @adc17, of course you can, just enclose the pattern in double quotes. For example ag "\'react-red.*\'"'

Comment: ...but if you *really* need to only use single quotes with regex, then follow this pattern: single quote the pattern and double quoting single quotes inside the pattern, for example:  ag '''DD-MON-YYYY''[\)\sA-z]*' would match: 'DD-MON-YYYY' ) AS created,  -- note, this is just a variant on the triple single quote recipe I mentioned above.

Comment: Double-quotes works. When I asked the question, I'd had trouble using special regex chars like ^ and $ with double quotes, but it seems to be working fine now.