# Sed with special caracters

Tags: regex, linux, shell, sed, escaping

How can I replace this with `sed` ? I need to replace this:

```
set $protection 'enabled';
```

to

```
set $protection 'disabled';
```

Please note that I can't sed the `enabled` to `disabled` because it's not only used at this location in the input file.

I tried this but it didn't change anything but gave me no error:

```
sed -i "s/set $protection 'enabled';/set $protection 'disabled';/g" /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape single quote in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509214/how-to-escape-single-quote-in-sed)

Comment: one of the solution suggested in the duplicate is to use double quotes, but in OP's case here, there are characters like `$` that causes issue.. so use the other tricks mentioned..

Comment: Simpler alternative for this case: `sed -i '/^set $protection/s/enabled/disabled/' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the following `sed` command:

**CMD:**

```
sed "s/set [$]protection 'enabled';/set \$protection 'disabled';/g"
```

Explanations:

- Just use double quote and add the `$` in a class character group to avoid that your shell interprets `$protection` as a variable
- If you need to modify a file change your command into: `sed -i.back "s/set [$]protection 'enabled';/set \$protection 'disabled';/g"` it will take a backup of your file and do the modifications in-place.
- Also you can add starting `^` and closing `$` anchors to your regex if there is nothing else on the lines you want to change. `^set [$]protection 'enabled';$`

**INPUT:**

```
$ echo "set \$protection 'enabled';"
set $protection 'enabled';
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
$ echo "set \$protection 'enabled';" | sed "s/set [$]protection 'enabled';/set \$protection 'disabled';/g"
set $protection 'disabled';
```

Comment: just run : `sed -i.bak "s/set [$]protection 'enabled';/set \$protection 'disabled';/g" <INPUT_FILE>`, take a backup of your file just in case, should be taken automatically!

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^set $protection '\''enabled'\'';$/c set $protection '\''disabled'\'';' file
```

Change the line to the required value.