# Adding single quotes into a sed command and also in a ssh command

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I'm in trouble doing a sed command inside an ssh call. I need to use single quotes in my sed command. Here is my command line :

```
ssh root@192.168.0.32 "sed -i '/0 => '192.168.0.32' /a 1 => '$old',' /tmp/test"
```

Here is the file :

```
<?php
$CONFIG = array (
  'trusted_domains' =>
  array (
    0 => '192.168.0.32',
  ),
  'dbtype' => 'mysql',
  'dbport' => '',
  'dbtableprefix' => 'oc_',
  'logtimezone' => 'UTC',
  'installed' => true,
  'redis' =>
  array (
    'host' => '192.168.0.13',
    'port' => 9095,
  ),
  'mail_smtpmode' => 'sendmail',
  'mail_from_address' => 'noreply',
  'knowledgebaseenabled' => false,
  0 => 18,
  'loglevel' => 1,
  'maintenance' => false,
);
```

In this context, I want to add in the `trusted_domains` for example `1 => '192.168.0.1',` after the first element.

The problem of the command is that he doesn't recognize the single quotes inside the sed command.

Don't forget, the sed command is inside a ssh command

Comment: Doesn't work too I tested it. It doesn't find the line but he can add the single quotes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape single quote in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509214/how-to-escape-single-quote-in-sed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try the following command (replace the username, hostname accordingly to your needs):

```
ssh toto@localhost "sed '/0 => \x27192.168.0.32\x27/a 1 => \x27$old\x27,' /tmp/test"
```

**output:**

```
<?php
$CONFIG = array (
  'trusted_domains' =>
  array (
    0 => '192.168.0.32',
1 => '1.1.1.1',
  ),
  'dbtype' => 'mysql',
  'dbport' => '',
  'dbtableprefix' => 'oc_',
  'logtimezone' => 'UTC',
  'installed' => true,
  'redis' =>
  array (
    'host' => '192.168.0.13',
    'port' => 9095,
  ),
  'mail_smtpmode' => 'sendmail',
  'mail_from_address' => 'noreply',
  'knowledgebaseenabled' => false,
  0 => 18,
  'loglevel' => 1,
  'maintenance' => false,
);
```

If this works, just add `-i` options if you are really sure about what you are doing. you can also do the `-i.bak` to force `sed` to take a back up of your files

Comment: Then your file is not located in the proper folder in the remote server: 
try `ssh root@192.168.0.32 "ls /tmp/test"` it will give you the same error normally... than the `sed` command. When you have adapted the path try it again

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thank you buddy! I have been out for a while but I shall come back slowly to the community!!! Wow you have contributed so much to the community when I was out

Answer (score 3):

Let's minimize this problem (and in the process of it realize, that most of your context could be stripped from your question.) First we define a helper function `args` to understand how the commands are split into words

```
$ args() { for x in "$@"; do echo "[$x]"; done; }

$ old=0.0.0.0
$ args ssh root@192.168.0.32 "sed -i '/0 => '192.168.0.32' /a 1 => '$old',' /tmp/test"
[ssh]
[root@192.168.0.32]
[sed -i '/0 => '192.168.0.32' /a 1 => '0.0.0.0',' /tmp/test]
```

Therefore a single argument (`"sed -i ..."`) is passed to `ssh`. The double
quotes are necessary for the variable expansion to take place but we can
simplify the problem by inlining the `old` variable:

```
$ args sed -i '/0 => '192.168.0.32' /a 1 => '0.0.0.0',' /tmp/test
[sed]
[-i]
[/0 => 192.168.0.32 /a 1 => 0.0.0.0,]
[/tmp/test]
```

We can simplify this further

```
$ args '/0 => '192.168.0.32' /a 1 => '0.0.0.0','
[/0 => 192.168.0.32 /a 1 => 0.0.0.0,]
```

and replacing the complicated argument with a much simpler one

```
$ args 'foo'1'bar'
[foo1bar]
```

Notice that the three strings `'foo'`, `1` and `bar` are concatenated to the
single world `foo1bar`. And now you can ask a simpler question:

> How can I add a single quote to the string `'foo'1'bar'`? And the answer is:

```
$ args 'foo'\'1\''bar'
[foo'1'bar]
```

Note though that `"foo'1'bar"` does not work in your case since you already used the double quotes for the outer `ssh` command.

Comment: I tested like `sed -i '/0 => '192.168.0.32' /a 1 => '0.0.0.0',' /tmp/test` but still no change. And what is args ?

Comment: How carefully did you read the answer? It should explain `args` and should also empower you to debug the problem yourself.