# Replacing with single quote using sed

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sed

I want to replace a set of characters with `'` using `sed`.

[This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33005/27925) suggest:

> With single quotes around the argument (sed `'s/…/…/'`), use `'\''` to put a single quote in the replacement text.

So, I tried following:

```
echo 'abcd' | sed 's/[abcd]/\'/g'
```

But it simply ends up expecting more input:

```
anir@DESKTOP-4856511:~$ echo 'abcd' | sed 's/[abcd]/\'/g'
>
>
>
> ^C
```

When I copy pasted `echo 'abcd' | sed 's/[abcd]/\'/g'` in `.sh` file and ran, it gave me following error:

```
anir@DESKTOP-4856511:~/Mahesha999/delete$ ./trysed.sh
./trysed.sh: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
./trysed.sh: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

What the right way to do this? Is it impossible to escape single quote inside single quoted string (and I have to use double quotes only as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509214/how-to-escape-single-quote-in-sed))?

Comment: Use `sed "s/[abcd]/'/g"` or `sed 's/[abcd]/'"'"'/g'`

Comment: the post you linked at the end also mentions `'s/ones/one\x27s/'` and `sed 's/ones/two'\''s/'`

Comment: @Sundeep whats that `\x27s` there?

Comment: @anir : Wouldn't be a `tr abcd "'"` easier than using _sed_?

Comment: @anir `\xNN` allows you to specify a character with two digit hexadecimal value, `27` is for single quote, see https://ascii.cl for mapping.. and [my tutorial](https://learnbyexample.github.io/learn_gnused/breere-regular-expressions.html#escape-sequences) for more details about such escape sequences and how the meaning can differ in replacement section

Comment: @Sundeep got it `\x27` is ascii code for `'`

Comment: @Sundeep is this issue only limited for replacement text?  The first link in my question says so.

Comment: strictly speaking, this isn't a `sed` issue, but shell issue... bash doesn't allow escaping single quote within single quotes, but it is possible in double quotes.. if you use `-f` option and [provide a file as source of sed commands](https://learnbyexample.github.io/learn_gnused/z-s-and-f-command-line-options.html#file-as-source-of-sed-commands), you won't run into this issue

Answer (score -1):

As the post says:

> With single quotes around the argument (`sed 's/…/…/'`), use `'\''` to put a single quote in the replacement text.

So, using your example, you would do:

```
echo 'abcd' | sed 's/[abcd]/'\''/g'
```

If you want to replace with just one single quote:

```
echo 'abcd' | sed 's/[abcd][abcd]*/'\''/g'
```

---

The shell does not allow single quotes inside a single quoted string. What the code above does is create *three* strings (which are not separated by anything):

- single-quoted string: `'s/[abcd]/'`
- unquoted string containing just an escaped single-quote: `\'`
- single-quoted string: `'/g'`

The shell then expands them and because they are not separated, they effectively become joined into a single string.

`sed` sees: `s/[abcd]/'/g`