# Replace value in single quotes using sed

Tags: sed

I already know that sed uses own approach to deal with single quote but I think it still possible to use it in my automation script.
I had to replace value of fingerprint in [Saltstack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(software)) config file.

Current value:

```
#master_finger: ''
```

Target value

```
master_finger: 'some:value'
```

My current command which doesn't work:

```
$ sed -i 's/#master_finger: ''/master_finger: 'some:value'/g' /etc/salt/minion
```

returns:

```
master_finger: some:value''
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape single quote in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509214/how-to-escape-single-quote-in-sed)

Comment: Not exactly. Especially if you look at answer below

Comment: The answer below says the same: use double quotes ("*Quote sed codes with double quotes*"). This is a 100% duplicate.

Comment: Added here for completeness `<<<"#master_finger: ''" sed -E 's/#(master_finger: ('\''))\2/\1some:value\2/'` N.B. Double quotes allow for the interpolation of the shell which may not always be desired. Whereas single quotes do not.

Comment: with respect to `sed uses own approach to deal with single quote` - no it doesn't. Not sure what you meant by that but single quotes to sed are the same as single quotes to any other Unix tool. Having to write a script that removes `#` in addition to dealing with `'`s is just adding an unnecessary complication to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use the double quotes to enclose the script.

```
$ echo "#master_finger: ''" | sed "s/#master_finger: ''/master_finger: 'some:value'/"

master_finger: 'some:value'
```

Comment: Single quotes can be managed but it is not pretty `<<<"#master_finger: ''" sed -E 's/#(master_finger: '\'')('\'')/\1some:value\2/'`

Comment: That exposes the script to the shell for globbing, word splitting, variable expansion, command execution, etc. - I'd only enclose a script in double quotes if you **need** that to happen.

Answer (score 0):

It's not sed that's making handling of `'`s difficult, it's the shell because the shell does not allow `'`s within any `'`-quoted string, including scripts.

You could save the sed script in a file and run it with `-f` or use a here document:

```
$ sed -f- file <<'EOF'
s/#master_finger: ''/master_finger: 'some:value'/g
EOF
master_finger: 'some:value'
```

To see the difference between the above and @karakfas suggestion:

```
$ sed -f- file <<'EOF'
s/#master_finger: ''/master_finger: '$(date)'/g
EOF
master_finger: '$(date)'
```

```
$ sed "s/#master_finger: ''/master_finger: '$(date)'/" file
master_finger: 'Sun Feb 14 06:50:43 CST 2021'
```

and imagine if `date` was replace by `rm -rf *` or something worse.

Also consider:

```
$ sed 's/#master_finger: '\'\''/master_finger: '\''$(date)'\''/' file
master_finger: '$(date)'
```