# Replace & with chr(38) using SED

Tags: sed

I am trying to replace & using chr(38)using sed but I keep getting error.

```
 cat line.txt -- Partners & Customers

 sed  's/&/' || chr(38) || '/g' line.txt
```

I get below error.

```
 -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `38'
```

I tried escaping ( and ) but it didn't help.

Regards.

Comment: You're trying to put two singlequotes _within_ a shell token defined by singlequotes. For this case (though not in general) you can use doublequotes: `"s/&/' || chr(32) || '/g"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape single quote in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509214/how-to-escape-single-quote-in-sed)