# MySQL query via SSH giving ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, ssh

ssh root@ip "mysql -uroot -p -e 'grant all on wordpress.* to firaswp@'ip' identified by 'password123';'"

however, when I input grant all on wordpress.* to firaswp@'54.87.224.199' identified by 'password123'; in mysql daemon it works fine..

does anyone know why this wouldn't be working? the syntax should be fine - if i remove "identified by 'password123', it works. Thanks!

Comment: You have a classical problem of quotation within quotation. [You need escaping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/escaping-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings).

Comment: Still a bit confusing, primarily, because I used single quotes without 'password123', and it work's fine. It's only after adding "identified by 'password'; in that the syntax breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this, and it works for me:

`ssh root@ip "mysql --user=user --password=pass database -e 'query'"`

Your script also look working but don't use `;` in command.

Comment: I just tried it again - it didn't work, I got ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'password' at line 1 - I did remove the ;, too.