# How to remove/strip double or single quote from a string?

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I have a file with some lines like these:

```
ENVIRONMENT="myenv"
ENV_DOMAIN='mydomain.net'
LOGIN_KEY=mykey.pem
```

I want to extract the parts after the `=` but without the surrounding quotes. I tried with `gsub` like this:

```
awk -F= '!/^(#|$)/ && /^ENVIRONMENT=/ {gsub(/"|'/, "", $2); print $2}'
```

Which ends up with `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token ')'` error. It works just fine for single matching: `/"/` or `/'/` but doesn't work when I try match either one. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It should be escaped like `\)` and Is single quote allowed within single quotes?

Comment: It is just a typo in `gsub()` function: you use `'` to close the quoting instead of `"`. Just replace `/"|'/` with `/"|"/`.

Comment: Three comments: (1) what about _ill formed_ definition: `ENVIRONMENT='old env"` (2) what about embedded quotes: `ENVIRONMENT="good ol'env"` (3) The two parts of your selector are redundant: `/^(#|$)/` cannot be true if `/^ENVIRONMENT=/` is true.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escaping single-quotes within single-quoted strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/escaping-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings)

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Once rewritten to work (something like this : `awk -F= '!/^(#|$)/ {gsub(/"|'"'"'/, "", $2); print $2}' myfile`), it will remove the quotes in your case 1) or 2).

Comment: awk fundamental 1: you cannot use a `'` inside a `'`-delimitted script. You need to use `\047` or some other method instead of the literal `'`' character. awk fundamental 2: you cannot have 2 separate "start-of-line-regexp" conditions that are both true. Get the book "Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition" by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: @Ploutox But is the middle `'` removal desired is case (2) ? For `ENVIRONMENT` this is kind of stupid, but might be relevant, say, for `PASSWORD="my good ol'passwd"`.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux: Point taken!! w.r.t. *ill formed* value, (1) is highly possible but targeting `"` or `'` should handle that corner. (2) is possible but unlikely according to possible values here that can be supplied. (3) is interesting and you are absolutely right - both cannot be true at the same time. Corrected in my original code.

Answer (score 5):

If you are just trying to remove the punctuation then you can do it as below....

```
# remove all punctuation
awk -F= '{print $2}' n.dat | tr -d [[:punct:]]

# only remove single and double quotes
awk -F= '{print $2}' n.dat | tr -d \''"\'
```

## explanation:

`tr -d \''"\'` is to delete any single and double quotes.
`tr -d [[:punct:]]` to delete all character from the punctuation class

Sample output as below from 2nd command above (without quotes):

```
myenv
mydomain.net
mykeypem
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with `awk`, but with `bash`.  The single quote inside the `gsub` is closing the open quote so that bash is trying to parse the command  `awk` with arguments `!/^...gsub(/"|/,`, `,`, `$2`  and then an unmatched close paren.  Try replacing the single quote with `'"'"'` (so that bash will properly terminate the string, then apply a single quote, then reopen another string.)

Answer (score 2):

Is `awk` really a requirement? If not, why don't you use a simple `sed` command:

```
sed -rn -e "s/^[^#]+='(.*)'$/\1/p" \
        -e "s/^[^#]+=\"(.*)\"$/\1/p" \
        -e "s/^[^#]+=(.*)/\1/p" data
```

This might seems over engineered, but it works properly with embedded quotes:

```
sh$ cat data
ENVIRONMENT="myenv"
ENV_DOMAIN='mydomain.net'
LOGIN_KEY=mykey.pem
PASSWD="good ol'passwd"
sh$ sed -rn -e "s/^[^#]+='(.*)'/\1/p" -e "s/^[^#]+=\"(.*)\"/\1/p" -e "s/^[^#]+=(.*)/\1/p" data
myenv
mydomain.net
mykey.pem
good ol'passwd
```

Comment: That is the only solution that works with quotes in the data.

Comment: In the case of quotes mismatch (i.e. `ENV_DOMAIN='mydomain.net"`) this doesn't remove the quotes. If that's an issue, you might want to consider `sed -rn -e "s/^[^#]+=(\"|')(.*)(\"|')$/\2/p" file`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` like this:

```
awk -F "=['\"]?|['\"]" '{print $2}' file
myenv
mydomain.net
mykey.pem
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work with your `awk`

```
awk -F= '!/^(#|$)/ && /^ENVIRONMENT=/ {gsub(/"/,"",$2);gsub(q,"",$2); print $2}' q=\' file
```

It is the single quote in the expression that create problems.  Add it to an variable and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

```
awk -F"=\"|='|'|\"|=" '{print $2}' file
myenv
mydomain.net
mykey.pem
```

This tells `awk` to use either `="`, `='`, `'` or `"` as field separator.

Comment: if you have a line with comment (or any text) containing a quote, some of it will be displayed

Comment: Yes, similar to some of the other solutions, it works only if no quotes are in the string. The only one that works correctly is that of Sylvain.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `awk` program must be enclosed in single quotes when run as a command line program.  The program can be tripped up if a single quote is contained inside the script.  Special tricks can be made to use single quotes as strings inside the program.  See [Shell-Quoting Issues](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Quoting.html) in the GNU Awk Manual.

One trick is to save the match string as a variable:

```
awk -F\= -v s="'|\"" '{gsub(s, "", $2); print $2}' file
```

Output:

```
myenv
mydomain.net
mykey.pem
```