# How to use Regular Expressions with Vim ag (silver search)

Tags: vim

I'm using Silver Search with the ag.vim plugin. Does anyone know how to use regex with the :ag command to search?

Comment: Can you give us an example regex and describe what you are trying to do?

Comment: Since ag.vim plugin has been deprecated in favour of [ack.vim](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim), you might want to check that one out. (ag.vim was a fork of ack.vim and there are really not a lot of differences).
reference: https://github.com/rking/ag.vim/issues/124#issuecomment-227038003

Answer (score 6):

Ag.vim needs some additional escaping (on top of what is needed for `ag`) because of vim, as stated in https://github.com/rking/ag.vim#gotchas.

For example, if you have the regexes, they need to be typed in Ag.vim as follows:

- `\.` is in Ag.vim `\\.`
- `\(` stays `\(` in Ag.vim
- `[` and `]` are in Ag.vim `\[` and `\]`
- `\s` becomes `\\\s` in Ag.vim
- `|` (options separator, e.g. in `(a|b|c)` is in Ag.vim `\|`
- `\.\s+async[^h]` is in Ag.vim `\\.\\\s\+async\[^h\]`

So to search for `\.\s+async[^h]`, you type `:Ag \\.\\\s\+async\[^h\]`. This is a little bloated with backslashes, but currently the only way I know to get the results.

I hope that gives you an idea of how to escape your regexes. For me, it took a little experimentation with the escaping.

Answer (score 3):

#### First off

According to [the ag.vim GitHub page](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim#can-i-use-ag-the-silver-searcher-with-this), ag.vim is now deprecated in favor of [ack.vim configured to use ag](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim#can-i-use-ag-the-silver-searcher-with-this). If you decide to go that route, just replace `:ag` with `:Ack` in the following and you're good to go.

#### And I Quote

ag.vim is automatically regex-enabled. **However,** to avoid backslash pollution, it's practically necessary to put your expression in `'single quotes'`, e.g. `:ag '[hw]eight'` to find `height`, `weight` but not `eight`. Otherwise, your Bourne-compatible shell will try to expand your pattern according to its own syntax before letting ag take it up.

#### Escapees

We're dealing with a Bourne-compatible shell here, so to escape single quotes see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings). tl;dr with my opinion mixed in: `'\''` is ugly but necessary.

(For the record, if the quote character comes at the beginning or end of your pattern, you can shave a couple singles off the end: `:ag \''cuz'` finds `'cuz`; `:ag 'runnin'\'` finds `runnin'`.)

Since you're in Vim, you'll still have to escape a couple characters that Vim would otherwise expand: `#` -> `\#`; `%` -> `\%`. (As of Jan 2023, running ack.vim on Neovim on a Mac, the gotcha [here](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim#can-i-use-ag-the-silver-searcher-with-this) doesn't apply.)

#### Pearly Writes

ag uses a PERL-family regex, which is rather different from Vim regex. (The good news is that it's pretty common nowadays, so you've probably encountered it before.) A couple gotchas:

In place of Vim's `\<` `\>` (word start and word end) use `\b` (word boundary).

Magic characters like `(` `)` `+` are always magic; escape to search for the literals:

```
:ag 'foo\(.*\)' " finds `foo()` and `foo(bar)` but not `foo`
:ag 'foo(.*)    " finds all three as well as `fool`

:ag '\b([A-Z]+_){2}[A-Z]+\b'   " finds every three-word name in CONSTANT_CASE
:ag '\b\([A-Z]\+_\){2}[A-Z]\+\b' " finds oddities like `(O+_))K+` (see why?)
```

#### Case Sensitivity

ag uses smart case-sensitivity, which can be overridden:

```
" Pattern has no uppercase: default to case-insensitive
:ag 'foo'            " matches `foo`, `Foo`, and `FOO`
" Force case sensitivity
:ag -s 'foo'         " matches `foo` but not `Foo` or `FOO`

" Pattern has any uppercase: default to case-sensitive
:ag 'Foo'            " matches `Foo` but not `foo` or `FOO`
" Force case insensitivity (equivalent to `:ag 'foo'`)
:ag -i 'Foo'         " matches `foo`, `Foo`, and `FOO`
```

Besides this, there are other options you can set while using ag, which you can read about by running `man ag` on the command line.

#### This ain't exhaustive

I probably missed something, just saying.

#### tl;dr

`'single quote'` your pattern,
escape your `#` `%`s with a backslash and make friends with the monster `'\''` (take a guess what for).
Then you've uncovered the pristine PERL--
though ag might still get on your case from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

`ag` uses the same syntax as `grep`:

```
$ ag .epart.    finds 'departure' and 'departed'
$ ag ^The       finds all lines starting with 'The'
$ ag s{2}       finds 'Odessa'
```

I'm not familiar with that `ag.vim` plugin but I guess that something like the following should find all lines ending with `Oz`:

```
:Ag Oz$
```

Refer to `$man grep` for the gory syntax details.