# Passing a string saved in a bash variable with an apostrophe to psql query using a bash script

Tags: psql

In a `BASH` script, I am reading in a list of strings from a text file that may contain apostrophe (`'`). Each string in the list is saved to a `BASH` environment variable that is passed to my psql query. I have tried everything so far but still when I loop through the list, if I counter an apostrophe, my query fails.

Here is a snipit of the code that fails:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE id = $myid AND name = '$namelist';
```

namelist is the file that has the entries which may contain apostrophes.

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

Use a [prepared SQL statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-prepare.html) to avoid SQL injection.

You may also need a solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings).