# How to update muiltiple documents in elasticsearch 1.5.2

Tags: elasticsearch, plugins, lucene

I am trying to update multiple documents on elasticsearch that were created with a wrong (for us) country name.

I am trying to do so by using "update_by_query" plugin version 2.5.0 (that should work with ES 1.5.2).  [plugin page](https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery/)

This is what I've tried:

```
POST incidents/political/_update_by_query
{
  "query":{
    "filtered":{
      "filter":{
        "bool":{
          "must":{
            "term":{
              "CountryName": "Cote d'Ivoire"          
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "script":{
    "inline":"ctx._source.CountryName = newName",
    "params":{
      "newName":"Cote dIvoire"
    }
  }
}
```

and the result is:

```
{
   "ok": true,
   "took": 9,
   "total": 2,
   "updated": 0,
   "indices": [
      {
         "incidents": {}
      }
   ]
}
```

I can see that it is able to find those two records but can't update them for some reason.

I have enable the needed settings on config file:

```
script.inline: on 
script.indexed: on
script.disable_dynamic: false
```

I am not sure what can be missing or wrong.

Comment: Did you try to add: script.engine.groovy.inline.update:on?

Comment: @alpert jus tried that and didn't work.

Comment: Maybe you can reindex your documents with correct values.

Comment: @alpert how can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to write the script part of your query like this:

```
 "script" : "ctx._source.CountryName = 'Cote dIvoire'"
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: thanks man! that worked like a charm. Can you tell me why my way wasn't  working ?

Comment: Glad I could help. I'm not quite sure. I ran into the same problem few days ago and this way solved my problem. :)

Comment: I ran into another issue, I need to add the quote but the script doesn't seem to accept special character. I tried by escaping it (\') or usin the html code (&#39;) but they didn't work. Any idea how to include it?

Comment: Hi @Yatiac, I think you can use quotes by using this five-character sequence '"'"'   check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings  Let me know if it works.

Comment: or Can you try to escape it with \u0027 . Check this link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/char-filters.html