# sed to remove all characters except letters and '

Tags: bash, sed

I am using this sed command to strip documents of all their (for me) unnecessary characters.

```
sed 's/[^a-zA-Z]/ /g'
```

However after mining my data a bit I realized a pretty basic mistake:
not including `'` cuts all my `don't`s into `don t`s, which sucks.

So i want to include `'` in my regex. I'm still new to this kind of "coding" if I may call it that way, so excuse my newbie mistake or even better, explain it to me!

`sed 's/[^a-zA-Z']/ /g'`   this obviously doesn't work

`sed 's/[^a-zA-Z\']/ /g'`   however this doesn't either, I thought `\` escapes the `'`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Good old double-quotes in action to protect the single quote without any need of escaping:

```
sed "s/[^a-zA-Z']/ /g" <<< "don't ... do this"
```

gives:

```
don't     do this
```

EDIT: your code seems to replace non-letters by space, but your question states otherwise, so I'm giving you the other version, to remove all non-letters/spaces and multiple occurrences of spaces as well (2nd expression).

```
sed -e "s/[^ a-zA-Z']//g" -e 's/ \+/ /' <<< "don't ... do this"
```

result:

```
don't do this
```

EDIT2: alternate solution to be able to keep single quotes (courtesy of Sundeep):

```
`'s/[^ a-zA-Z\x27]//g'`
```

Note: I first tried to escape single quotes following the solutions tested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings) and none using single quotes worked for me (always prompting for a line continuation) so I came up with those alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `tr -cd "'[:alnum:] "`

```
$ echo "some string '*'@'#'%^ without special chars except '" | tr -cd "'[:alnum:]"

$ somestring''''withoutspecialcharsexcept'
```

If you want the spaces:

```
echo "some string '*'@'#'%^ without special chars except '" | tr -cd "'[:alnum:] "
some string '''' without special chars except '
```