# Using SED in a ssh command on a remote node

Tags: bash, ssh, sed

I wrote a script to ssh to some nodes and run a `sed` command inside the node. The script looks like

```
NODES="compute-0-3"
for i in $NODES 
do
  echo $i
  ssh $i 'sed -i \'s/172.16.48.70/172.20.54.10/g\' /etc/hosts;'
done
```

However, the error is

```
unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

It seems that the character `'` is not treated as the begining of a `sed` command.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suggest to replace

```
ssh $i 'sed -i \'s/172.16.48.70/172.20.54.10/g\' /etc/hosts;'
```

by

```
ssh "$i" 'sed -i "s/172.16.48.70/172.20.54.10/g" /etc/hosts'
```

If you absolutely want to use single quotes:

```
ssh "$i" 'sed -i '"'"'s/172.16.48.70/172.20.54.10/g'"'"' /etc/hosts'
```

Comment: This might help: [How to escape single-quotes within single-quoted strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1250079/3776858)